# What are the moderation tools available to 10,000+ reputation users?

Tags: support, faq, 10k-tools, moderator-abilities, moderator-faq

The site FAQ refers to *moderation tools*, available to users who've earned more than 10,000 reputation:

> **10,000**   Delete closed questions, access to moderation tools

What are these tools exactly?

[Return to FAQ index](/q/7931)

[Return to Moderator FAQ index](/q/118972/350567)

Answer (score 106, accepted):

First off, see: [the Access to Moderator Tools privilege description](https://meta.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools). (Note: on beta sites and graduated sites without designs, you gain these privileges with just 2,000+ reputation.)

Each view is found in one of four categories: **links**, **stats**, **close**, and **delete**. There is also a tab for the same **review** view that is available to users who have yet to reach 10k. When you click on the **tools** option in the header, **stats** is the first category opened. It contains general lists:

- Highest voted questions sorted by vote
- Lowest voted questions sorted by vote
- Highest voted answers sorted by vote
- Lowest voted answers sorted by vote
- Most commented questions and answers sorted by number of comments
- Most viewed questions and answers sorted by number of views
- Most edited questions and answers sorted by number of edits
- Recently imported questions (those migrated from other sites)
- Tags that have been created recently, sorted by frequency of use

The **close** category has views relating to questions that have been or are being closed or reopened:

- Most close votes, sorted by number of votes
- Most reopen votes, sorted by number of votes
- Recently closed, sorted by time
- Recently reopened, sorted by time

The **delete** category has views relating to questions and answers that have been or are being deleted or undeleted:

- Most delete votes, sorted by number of votes
- Most undelete votes, sorted by number of votes
- Recently deleted (not by owner), sorted by time
- Recently undeleted (not by owner), sorted by time

Several pages contain a set of links to additional information in the footer:

- [Information on the moderator tools privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools)
- New answers to old questions
- Suggested edit statistics
- Anonymous and low-rep post feedback statistics (also accessible to all users via Stack Exchange Data Explorer)
- Question close stats
- Protected questions

For the **stats**, **close** and **delete** views, they are filtered by time span which is choosable by the user. The options are "30d", "14d", "7d", "2d" (default) and "today".

Users with 10k reputation can also:

- Search among their own deleted posts using `deleted:1`
- View any deleted question that they have the link to*
- See deleted answers when viewing a question, even [when deleted by the author](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/365/why-should-10k-rep-users-view-self-deleted-answers).*
- Vote to delete closed questions 48 hours after they were closed.

  - Users with 20,000+ reputation (4,000+ on beta sites) can *immediately* vote to delete closed questions if they score -3 or lower.
- See full history of each review queue on the History tab; <10K users can see only their own review history.

* If the posts were deleted as spam or rude/abusive, the contents will be hidden, and can only be viewed by accessing the revision history.

These lists help us see where intervention might be needed: where edit wars are going on, where new tags with typos have been made, which questions are spam, etc. They don't really give us any new power other than to delete questions the rest of the community has already decided doesn't belong on the site.

Answer (score 12):

In the top bar where you have the Logout, About, and FAQ options, there is another one added called Tools.

Basically the tools are just lists of items for different criteria.

Some examples:

- Questions with the most close votes
- Different lists of questions with heavy activity in terms of up votes, down votes, etc.

Once you hit 10k, it is almost a bit of a disappointment because you expected more powerful tools, but they serve their purpose, I suppose.

Comment: A "make it all better" button would be very useful, for example.