# "Diamond Moderator" vs "Moderator", are they the same?

Tags: discussion, moderators, terminology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Who are the diamond moderators, and what is their role?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/who-are-the-diamond-moderators-and-what-is-their-role)

I usually refer to the elected mods (and community/dev/etc mods) as just that, a "mod" or "moderator", but lately I've read a lot of posts that use the phrase "**diamond** mod(erator)".  I would like to know if there is a difference between a "Diamond Moderator" and a "Moderator"?  Is a diamond mod a user with more/different privileges or permissions then a regular mod.  Do *non*-diamond mods exist, or is this just a -verbose way of saying moderator?

---

Not sure how this is a dup, wasn't asking what is a Diamond mod or what their role is, I wanted to know if there was an actual ***NON***-diamond mod rank.  No biggy though, thanks all for your insight and comments.

Comment: See [a general overview of diamond mods](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/who-are-the-diamond-moderators-and-what-is-their-role) and [the difference between diamond mods and 10ks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14457/diamond-moderator-privileges-vs-10k-rep-privileges), *probable duplicate of the second?*

Comment: Newer users, who don't know how everything works on SE, often refer to "actions taken by moderators" when they mean other ordinary, though high-rep, users of the site. 10k users are _de facto_ moderators -- they hold no official title, but the new users naturally (and I think fairly) see their actions (editing, voting to close/open/delete, providing guidance in comments, and so on) as "moderation".

Comment: Still then, @Iulius, I feel it's fine to explain to those new users that 10k's are not moderators. As for voting to close, any 3k could be called a moderator too then. As as for editing, anyone who can suggest an edit could be called a moderator then ;-)

Comment: @Arjan: Oh, absolutely; I don't think we should start using the term that way, or stop explaining things to newer users. I just wanted to explain why this comes up at all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Diamond moderators are either community elected or appointed. There's a list of all diamond moderators [here](https://stackexchange.com/about/moderators). The term *diamond* refers the fact that they have a diamond (♦) next to their names.

Diamond moderators aside, Stack Overflow is community moderated.

At `10000` rep, users gain [access to moderator tools](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools), so the term *moderator* can also refer to a user with `10k` rep or more.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't know 10k+ was also referred to as mods.. That makes sense, thanks.

Comment: I don't think 10k's are *rightfully* referred to as moderators. True, some do, but I feel that's wrong, @chown.

Comment: @chown they're "community moderators" in the sense that most SE users can provide some method of moderation, but no one particularly uses the term "moderators" to refer to them, they're just 10k users.

Answer (score 3):

"Diamond mod" is just used to reinforce the mapping of "diamond by name" => mod. We no longer have tiers of moderators. A mod is a diamond mod.

Comment: Thanks for the infoz.  I assumed this was the case, just wasn't sure.

Comment: Were there ever tiers of moderators?