# Where can someone read up on the tools Mods have access to as opposed to high rep users?

Tags: support, moderator-tools

One of my concerns about myself going for a moderator position in an election is that one of the general questions that are gathered as very common questions asked every election is

> In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

[Source](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3895/1587)

Now sure this question may not actually be asked but when I try to evaluate on whether I can be a good mod I look over all the questions and see if I can answer them all. With the above question I just wouldn't be able to give an answer. I know Mods have access to more tools that what those with high rep have access to but I don't know what these tools are or even how they work.

I want to change that. I would like to know where someone can read up on the tools Mods have access to as opposed to what high rep users have access to.

Comment: Would that include using search?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136890/whats-the-difference-between-a-moderator-and-someone-who-has-access-to-moderato

Comment: @random if by that you mean typing "mod tools" into the search box in the top right, well when i did that i got *"How can we improve the mod tools?"*, *"Dimmed things in mod tools"*, *"Feature-request: mod tools: Chatroulette 'Next'"*. in fact your duplicate didn't appear at all in the first 50 results even when i searched for *"moderator tools"*

Comment: This is a bit of an XY Problem: the mod tools that you can't see *aren't* what make the biggest difference. The mod-only actions that are visible are the most important difference, and are things that you should already be familiar with by witnessing them in action, if contemplating a moderation election run.

Comment: For what it's worth, I wouldn't interpret that question as trying to quiz you on your familiarity with the details of moderator tools. If you're generally aware of what mods do (e.g. handle flags, rarely warn/suspend users) and what they *don't* do (e.g. the community mostly runs the site via meta), you know enough to think about the question.

Comment: Oh, and there's also a summary in the help center (same on every site), which I think easily covers everything you'd need to know here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators