# What does 10k (10000 or 10,000) rep unlock?

Tags: discussion, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What facilities are there in the moderation tools?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4565/what-facilities-are-there-in-the-moderation-tools)

What does reputation above 10k gain you in terms of moderation tools? I'm getting close on Stack Overflow and I'm curious.

Comment: duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4565/what-facilities-are-there-in-the-moderation-tools

Comment: Mod: Please don't delete this.

Comment: If it is a duplicate, why would it matter if they delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You crack open the [pantry of moderation tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4565/what-facilities-are-there-in-the-moderation-tools/4576#4576).

Comment: That and $3.89 will buy you a latte.