# Allow 3k users to see the pending close-vote question queue

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

On Stack Overflow it might look like it doesn't make much sense but it would make sense on smaller SE sites where there are not that many 10k users. On Ask Ubuntu the way we handle this right now is to have a separate chat room where we can post questions that need to be closed.

Wouldn't it make more sense to let 3k users see the pending close-vote question queue if they are allowed to cast a close vote?

Or lets put it this way. What is the reason behind the decision to only let 10k users see that queue?

Comment: I imagine it's a similar reason as why only 10k+ users can see pending suggested edits.

Comment: @Cody What's that reason?

Comment: @Anna: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80070/why-set-the-bar-so-high-for-viewing-suggested-edits-review-tab Not everyone *agrees*, of course, but that seems to be the official stance.

Comment: In addition to what @CodyGray has linked, I also recommend this [old, yet still useful reading](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39420/why-is-10-000-rep-needed-to-access-moderation-tools) on why 10000 reputation is needed to access the various moderation tools (including pending close votes).

Comment: @CodyGray I'm less than 10k on SO (as of the time of this comment), but I can still see pending suggested edits in the review thing. I think it's actually a 5k thing now.

Comment: @Peter: It is indeed 5k; that happened [about two months ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105755/roll-out-10k-tools-gradually-between-3k-and-10k-reputation-for-users-who-have-sh/105870#105870). Perhaps with that change, this one will also be reviewed.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111838/why-was-review-close-taken-away-for-under-10k-users-can-it-be-put-back

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's extend that close vote paddock to show alongside that somewhere a beacon of close flags from users below 3000.

You'll get the cleaning community more involved at an earlier stage.

The 3k-10k users will see how it is to review question flags and you have sub 3k users learning about what type of questions the community also deem to be unworthy of staying open.

The close question flaggers are thrust upon their peers and get a gist of what types of questions are worthy to stay on the site and you're not making training wheels out of your moderators.

Make these community close flags peer reviewable and you have:

- If two other users disagree, that's a disputed flag which then bubbles up to a moderator
- They agree and cast their own close vote and the rest of the close vote train follows in course.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that lower rep users should have access to the closed question queue. I was just about to post a question about it, but I found this so I'll add it here. I was going to suggest users should get the close queue when they get the edit queue, at 5k, but I think 3k is reasonable too. 2ks don't get the edit queue because they can't yet approve tag wikis, so it makes sense to keep that 5k+; 3ks, on the other hand, have access to all the review actions (up/downvote, edit, comment, vtc, flag, delete) except delete, and questions eligible for deletion by mere mortals (non-mods) don't even appear in that queue (so why is it a listed action? for mods only?). So why restrict the queue to 10ks?  I've seen a mod complain that not enough people are casting close votes, and lowering the threshold will help with that, especially on sites with only a handful of 10k users where that's a problem.

Comment: 5k users don't see the "close" tab in the review page too. That is something only 10k users can see.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I know. Is there something that suggests 5ks can see it now? I can reword it.

Comment: I was referring to, "3ks, on the other hand, have access to all the review actions except delete." Only the review page is visible to non-10k users, and in that page there isn't a "delete" tab; then, not even 5k users have access to all the tabs in the review page.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I was referring to the all the actions one can take on a question being reviewed, i.e. those in the "Your Review Stats" list: upvote/downvote, edit, comment, vtc, flag, delete.