# Edit queue available to heavy editors across all sites

Tags: feature-request, edits, review, suggested-edits

I don't like the decision for basing the ability to have more 'power' in editing with higher rep users -- just 'cause you have 10k rep doesn't mean you can pwn me (~2.5k rep) at editing. But that's another story.

Technically, someone could make something that would go through all the recent suggested edits. All they need to do is search the most recent suggested edits, and filter out the ones rejected or approved.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/ INSERT HIGH NUMBER.
```

So what's the point of having the editing queue available to only 10k users? I have made over a thousand edits on SE, and I think I can tell the difference between an edit to approve and an edit to reject. (Notice I didn't say "good/bad edit".)

StackExchange is suppposed to be like Wikipedia, right? So give the good editors more privileges **across sites**, regardless of whether they have enough rep or not!

In fact: I propose an integrated edit queue on StackExchange. You can look at the edit queue for sites/tags you indicate.

---

### TL;DR

- Editing privileges based on number of quality edits (Wikipedia style).
- Editing privileges are sustained across different SE sites.
- An edit queue on stackexchange.com.

Comment: Just patience, muntoo. We will all be there soon.

Comment: But many thanks for your hundreds (thousands?) of edits on SO. :)

Comment: @sarnold I don't think it's in the thousand_s_ yet. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Firstly, it's not 10k anymore. The edit queue is now shown to 5k users as a partial fulfillment of [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105755/roll-out-10k-tools-gradually-between-3k-and-10k-reputation-for-users-who-have-sh). However, I **do not** support your idea of a network wide edit queue.

I moderate two sites on the network: Gardening & Signal processing and I can tell you from first hand experience that the edit queues in both the site are *very* different. On gardening, the edits are mostly minor and involve link fixes/grammar corrections/image fixes/overall improvements to the post. These are pretty easy to approve/reject and doesn't require much thinking.

However, on a highly specialized site like signal processing, there were some suggested edits that have stayed in the queue for 5-6 days (*days!*), because none of the mods (and one user who could see the queue) knew much about the subtopic related to the question. We eventually ended up reading a bit about the subject, discussing the edit made and decided to approve it.

Now I certainly cannot expect a random person who just happens to be an awesome editor on cooking.SE or christianity.SE to approve those edits, nor do I want them to! We don't want madmen correcting `/etc/passwd` on unix.SE to `/etc/password` and someone on english.SE approving it!

Now you might say that oh well, a *good* editor would not approve partial/poor edits. **Wrong!** [Here's a recently approved](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/142054) edit on Stack Overflow. The person who suggested the change missed `lt;br&gt` several times  (one even right before his edit), a few lower case `i`'s and bungled up the spelling of grammar in his edit reason. This was even approved by 2 users! Can you imagine what would happen if we implemented an SE wide queue, and only 1 user is required to approve?

For these reasons, I **strongly** oppose any additional edit privileges on one site based on privileges earned on another. If you want to earn the privilege to edit, do it the hard way! Earn 2k rep. (or 1k on betas).