# Should some privileges be awarded when a user gets a badge?

Tags: feature-request, badges, privileges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Roll out 10k tools gradually between 3k and 10k reputation for users who have shown interest in helping the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105755/roll-out-10k-tools-gradually-between-3k-and-10k-reputation-for-users-who-have-sh)

There are a couple privileges that I believe would be better awarded along with badges instead of with rep. The example that I am thinking of the the edit questions and answers privilege ( https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit ). I think that this should be awarded with the copy editor badge ( https://stackoverflow.com/badges/223/copy-editor ) to give users who are active in editing the ability to review edits. I'm sure there are some other examples too.

Feel free to tell me I'm wrong

Edit - Privileges could be awarded for BOTH rep and a certain badge if some people would consider that easier

Comment: Let's say we start a new Stack Exchange site today. Obviously all users start without any badges. Who's reviewing their edit suggestions?

Comment: ...and right now SO has 553 Copy Editors. I don't think the site would survive for long if only 553 people were reviewing edits.

Comment: @Yannis: Obviously all users start without rep as well?

Comment: @Junuxx Obviously! But on the young Beta sites I participate in it's a _lot_ easier to get rep than find something to edit. For example, look at the Workplace (6 months old), [quite a few high rep users already](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all), but [not even a full page of editors](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/users?tab=editors&filter=all).

Answer (score 1):

One of the benefits of making the review queue so open, whether this was by design or not, is that it encourages more people to get involved in community moderation early and help provide them with the skills they'll need to do a good job on these sorts of things once they become 2K, 3K, and 10K users.

**Badges do two things:**

- They serve as goals for individuals to work towards to demonstrate they are doing good things for the site.
- When a site has a lot of badge holders under one category, this shows that the community is active in this specific area, and this can roughly indicate the health of that community.

As an example, the copy editor badge may encourage people who already have the edit privilege to do their part in fixing posts that need some help. As an example, a site that has a lot of copy editor badge-holders shows that the community has really strong editing participation.

**Reputation is for something different:**

Reputation, on the other hand, is a rough measurement of how much the community trusts you. This is determined by the community's response to actions that you perform on the site through asking questions, providing answers, and editing questions, answers, and tag wikis. Badges are more automated, whereas reputation is given by the community.

Mixing the two together would be a mistake. Badges have nothing to do with privileges and that's how it should be. Think of badges as "flair", sort of like the medals on a soldier's uniform. With that analogy, privileges would be related to the soldier's rank.