# Add a "Review posts with reopen votes" review task?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, reopen-closed

When a question is closed because it is considered to be "not constructive" or "not a real question", the text explicitly includes a hint that the question might be reopened after it has been improved/clarified, e.g.

> For help clarifying this question so that it can be reopened, see the FAQ.

Why aren't "reopen votes" included in the new review system, so that more good questions which get improved also get a chance (enough attention) to be reopened?

Comment: A separate reopen task for questions which have reopen votes could prove helpful. I don't see any reason not to add this.

Comment: Sounds good. With the vertical layout of review tasks it's easier to justify adding new tasks space-wise. This sounds like a worthy one

Comment: Strongly agree.  Super-upvote*! (*\*Note: super-upvote is no different from a normal upvote in this case, unfortunately*)

Comment: @jadarnel27 Feature request?!? Kidding, I think that's been proposed a handful of times.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39420/why-is-10-000-rep-needed-to-access-moderation-tools) insofar as it touches on who should have access to such a queue.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148204/can-we-get-some-more-review-queues-questions-with-delete-votes-recently-close

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The **Reopen Votes** [review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review) is now live!

> Vote whether or not to reopen closed questions with reopen votes

In most ways, it's the mirror image of the Close Votes review queue. The available review actions are:

> - **Leave Closed** if this question is not appropriate for the site in its current state
> - **Edit and Reopen** to correct the issues with this question prior to reopening
> - **Reopen** if all issues with this question have been corrected, or it was incorrectly closed
> - **Not Sure** if you are unsure and want to skip this question

Similarly to "Do Not Close" reviews, if a question gets 3 "Leave Closed" reviews, the post is immediately removed from the Reopen Votes review queue, and the reopen votes will begin to age away.

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMZj9.png]

Comment: How do questions get onto the Reopen queue? It sounds like at least one person has to vote to reopen before a question is listed there, which seems a bit of a chicken-and-egg problem. Is there a way to search for closed questions that have been edited, but that *don't* have any reopen votes yet?

Comment: I think this did not work out exactly how author intended: http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/history ...  Do mods have statistics for the review queues? It would be nice to know how many question were reopened. Three topics? Maybe four?

Answer (score 35):

This is fair.

Note that there are no review queues for delete / undelete at present either - we're limiting the scope in order to get the kinks worked out, but the number of queues *will* be expanded. I certainly don't see a problem with reviewing questions nominated for re-opening.

FYI: there are currently 944 closed questions on Stack Overflow with pending re-open votes (vs. something like 58K for pending close votes).

Comment: Thanks for the insights!

Comment: Don't forget that close votes don't expire on questions with < 100 views, while reopen votes are typically on questions with > 100 views so expire after a few days. This is probably part of why the difference is so great, although I'm sure the fact you need a closed question before you can get reopen votes also plays a role :)