# Add "Questions edited after closing" review task

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, edits, review, closed-questions

As implied by user bemace [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143010/policy-enforcement-time-for-an-so-site-for-all-the-things-soisnt#comment406098_143010), what if the new `/review` included a "Questions edited after closing"  list? This would make it *much* more likely that improved questions would be reopened, making SO a friendlier, happier place, with more unicorns and waffles all around.

Comment: related (not a duplicate): [Add a “Review posts with reopen votes” review task?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/140893/165773)

Comment: Isn't being edited one of the things that will kick a question into the re-open queue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has been implemented now. Whenever a question is edited after it is closed, it will be added in to a [reopen review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen) queue.

E.g. take a look at [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/1977348). It was added to a reopen queue after being edited.

> [image]

It also shows the revision made after the question was closed.

> [image]

Answer (score 3):

This. And if it is re-opened then any voting should be reset to zero for reconsideration by the community at large. That would restore the asker's rep as a reward for doing something worthwhile with the question, too.

Comment: What if the vote is net-positive?