# Better visibility for closed posts that have been edited

Tags: feature-request, edits, closed-questions, review, reopen-closed

I would like to see *something* that gives closed posts that have been edited a little more visibility.

All edits bump the thread back to the front page, but there it tends to be drowned out in the noise. In particular, there is no indication as to whether the question has been edited after closing. There's no way to distinguish between “closed question, 99% chance that I won't disagree with the closing, I'm not even looking” and “closed question that's been edited, maybe I should see if it warrants reopening”.

While flagging for reopening is an option, this requires that the editor can flag and knows that he should flag. Besides, it would be better if reopening could be achieved by the community in practice (not really the case on less-trodden SO tags or on smaller sites). Replying to a comment can also bootstrap the reopening process, but only if high-enough-reputation users commented. When the asker is a new user, passively waiting for reopen votes is often all they can do and know how to do.

Since there are new review queues in the works, I think this should be part of one of them, perhaps together with the questions with reopen votes, but I don't have a precise implementation in mind. What I'm asking for is some way of having these closed-then-edited questions reach potential reopeners, without being lost in a sea of other boring stuff.

Note that this feature request is purposely different from [Notify close voters when a closed question gets edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56849/notify-close-voters-when-a-closed-question-gets-edited). I don't think the people who did the closing should necessarily be the ones judging to reopen. Once edited, the post should be thrown back to the community in general — if only because the closers might not be around.

Comment: Would [Add "Questions edited after closing" review task](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143013) work?

Comment: @TimStone Thanks, that's exactly what I was thinking of. I'm not sure whether to consider it an *exact* duplicate given that I'm not specifically hung up on this particular implementation, but if I'd found that I wouldn't have bothered posting my request.