# Alert Closers of questions when a 'good' edit is made?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits, closed-questions

Often I vote to close, or just close a question in the hopes that a good edit is made on a poor question, to make it ship-shape and sea-worthy. I know this isn't always the case, but I live in the hope that closed questions can be improved on in most cases.

The issue I have (though minor) is that if one of these 'good' edits is made, one that salvages a poor question into something useful and worthwhile, I'd like to know. I've invested myself in the question enough to get it closed, I'd like to know if it's been fixed, so I can vote to reopen it.

I see obvious issues for people who close a lot of questions, with little investment in them. The questions are just so poor that they won't ever see the light of day (but, perhaps aren't deleted as they should come up in searches for similar questions). I *don't* want to flood users inboxes in this case, and I'm a little stumped as how to avoid this.

With that caveat above out of the way, I still think this is a valid attempt at removing '[broken windows](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/06/the-broken-window-theory.html)', when a question that should no longer be closed is.

Is this sort of thing possible? How would we make it 'spam-free' if you don't want the alert?

Comment: How about you get the notification only if the question has been edited **and** someone else casts a reopen vote.

Comment: @Juhana that would be good. I've also seen this related question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143013/175002

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's really no need to inform users of these things. Questions that get closed and then edited in any way after that automatically bump into the Reopen Votes queue where they will be seen and reviewed by other people (yes, that question is cheating on you), who can decide to either reopen the question or leave it closed. It gets the attention it deserves, but not always from the people who originally closed it (unless you just happen to run across it there).

Most often when I review things in the reopen queue, they're silly edits that don't actually change anything (move words around, edit the answer into the question, or attempt to rage-quit and edit the question away completely). There are legitimate edits that really improve the question, but there's no way to separate that out well enough that inbox notifications would be worthwhile.

Comment: +1 for "that question is cheating on you". Oh, and a good answer, otherwise!