# Can we get some more review queues - questions with delete votes, recently closed etc.?

Tags: feature-request, review

The new /review queues are great, but there are some other lists on the /tools pages that could do with the same treatment.

- Recently closed questions
- <s>Questions with reopen votes</s> (this has been implemented)
- Recently reopened questions

These would be useful to find those questions that need improvement to be reopened or have been improved and require some reopen votes.

- Questions with delete votes
- Recently deleted questions
- Questions with undelete votes
- Recently undeleted questions

The first of these would help clean up some of the cruft on the site and the others would be a double check that the right questions were being deleted.

In addition to displaying questions with delete votes the `/delete` queue could display questions that were closed a long time ago (> 90 days?) and negatively scored ones and haven't been edited recently.

**NOTE:** Some of these lists already exist:

https://stackoverflow.com/tools?s=1&tab=close&daterange=today

and

https://stackoverflow.com/tools?s=1&tab=delete&daterange=today

But they are not very easy to use.

Comment: [You mean like running the existing questions tagged `homework` through the review queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147100/140951)?

Comment: @casperOne - not necessarily. I mean getting the lists from http://stackoverflow.com/tools?s=1&tab=close&daterange=today and http://stackoverflow.com/tools?s=1&tab=delete&daterange=today into the same format as the ones one the /review tab

Comment: No, I meant, I want to get those questions run through the review queue.  Wasn't looking for clarification on what *you* want.  It's not all about you! =)

Comment: Well why didn't you say so. But you will find it is all about me.

Comment: That would make those tabs much more useful. I just added a [related request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148604/167534) for updating the flag queue and the new answers to old questions list. Add your requests to mine, and the result would be a full revamp of /tools.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140893/add-a-review-posts-with-reopen-votes-review-task

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151345/suggested-migrations-review-at-target-site

Comment: Any chance on seeing a Delete queue implemented any time soon?

Comment: The lack of a delete queue in /review is a problem on pm.stackexchange.com, too. Yes, we know about 10K tools, but the /review queues are easier, better, and really ought to integrate votes for deletion.

Comment: Still nothing on this? Delete review queues have been requested in **2012** and nothing constructive has been done since then. I seem to be the only person on my site who routinely tries to clean up so 90% of the questions linked on the 10K tools I've already voted on.

Answer (score 26):

Some high-rep users regularly go through the recently-close-voted and recently-delete-voted queues accessible from the 10k tools. You can tell this is happening because you often wind up putting the final delete vote on postings whose first two delete votes are from the same small set of delete-voters, who are also running the queues like you are.

This isn’t as easy as it could be, as [detailed here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158210/delete-tab-doesnt-always-grey-things-out-that-it-should?lq=1).  Because it shows you posts you have already close- or delete-voted without indicating such, and so you cannot do so again but do not know that until you try, it wastes a lot of time. In volatile queues like on SO, it is not *too* bad — although I do get tired of trying to delete vote the things with five or ten delete votes on them already again and again and again.  But on sites with a less volatile delete queue, or fewer 10k or 20k users, it really is a royal waste of time.

Presumably if such things were available through the regular Review Queues, that bug would get fixed.

Comment: Yeah. I was hoping the delete queue (and the recently closed and recently deleted queues) would get migrated to the new system, but it doesn't seem to be happening.

Comment: While this might be the case, on sites with only few 10k+ users (like Android.SE) it is hard to run a cleanup task, as people are not always thinking of those mod-tools delete tab. I've got some hard times with those jobs, and many of my votes have been in vain because they expired. So I second ChrisF's request: I too wish for a delete-queue in the `/review` section!

Comment: @Izzy Yeah, close and unclose votes do evaporate quickly enough (well, within the constraints of certain parameters), but delete and undelete votes do not.

Comment: @tchrist Close and Reopen requests are part of the `/review` queue, so they get good attention. Delete and Undelete votes are not -- that's the difference. Call me a "purist", but I like to have our sites clean to be as useful as possible -- and "removing junk" belongs to that: 2 years old closed questions without any useful answer or even comment have no reason to stay. The only thing they might do is cluttering search results, which I cannot really call "useful" ;)

Comment: @Izzy I used to go through the most-negatively voted closed questions in order and pitch delete votes at the ones I thought did not add value to the site, but I always felt like I was pissing in the ocean — or at least, not spurring others to go and do likewise, since unless you looked at the recent delete votes listing, you never noticed.

Comment: Exactly the reason *I* want them in the `/review` queue, so they are not that easily missed.

Answer (score 9):

Questions with reopen votes have now been added to the queues.