# Are improvements to the 10k tools in the plans?

Tags: feature-request, review, 10k-tools

The 10k flag queue is currently listing over 500 posts, most flagged as low quality or for closure. I was thinking it would be much more pleasant to go through those posts if the tool were similar to the new review tasks.

**Is that something currently in the developers' plans?**

Maybe the flag queue could even be moved to /review (but still restricted to 10k), as well as the "New answers to old questions" list (the one whose link likes to run away from us while async content loads on the "stats" tab).

I think the review task approach of presenting one post at a time would work like a charm for those queues, and maybe the other lists from /tools could remain as they are (at least, changing those doesn't seem so important to me).

Comment: Related: [Can we get some more review queues - questions with delete votes, recently closed etc.?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148204/can-we-get-some-more-review-queues-questions-with-delete-votes-recently-close)