# The question-expanding drag-handle is missing from the 10k flag queue

Tags: bug, status-completed, 10k-tools, flag-queue

> [image]

The expanded view of a flagged answer used to show a preview of the question, which could be expanded via a drag handle... which has recently disappeared.

Please sir, could it be added back?

<sup>Chrome 25.0.1364.97 m, Windows 8, no errors in `console`, BTW</sup>

Comment: I was going to post about that too, but I'm too slow. I fully endorse this request.

Comment: Ha! I just got caught by that. Flagged an answer as not an answer because it looked confusing. I thought the question was part of the answer: http://i.imgur.com/IOIFR8q.png. Okay then, +1 on my declined flag count...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was some javascript removed during a refactoring - it should now be restored.

Answer (score 1):

This is still the case network-wide, I've run into it on 4 different sites today. Can we at least get some official statement that a fix is coming? Preferably within 6-8 weeks.

Answer (score 1):

I really wish that the handle will eventually go away for good, in favor of a [better user interface for the flag queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148604/are-improvements-to-the-10k-tools-in-the-plans). So I hope it's not working because the devs are working on a replacement.

I review many posts using an iPad, and those handles simply don't work on a touch screen. I even asked a [question/bug report about that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128735/cannot-view-full-question-when-reviewing-posts-on-ipad)<sup>10k link</sup>, but it was deleted (for inactivity, maybe?).

Comment: Couldn't agree more about the better interface being needed :)

Comment: We know there's some UX pain here; hopefully, [Jeremy](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/202998/jeremy-tunnell) can look at it after some unrelated improvements he's working on.

Comment: @JarrodDixon I'm glad the team is aware of the UX problems. It would be great to hear from Jeremy about his ideas for improving the 10k tools, when he finds some time.