# Delete tab doesn’t always grey things out that it should

Tags: feature-request, 10k-tools, vote-to-delete, vote-to-undelete, trusted-user

(I don’t quite know whether this is a bug or a feature, but I’ll be charitable and mark it as a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) for now.    Please feel free to retag to [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) if you decide otherwise.)

In the Delete tab under the  Tools page, posts that you cannot yourself delete (or undelete) are shown greyed out, for such reasons as:

- The posting is locked.
- It was deleted by a moderator.
- You’re 10k only but it’s an answer not a question.
- The answer has previous delete votes, but is currently non-negative. (Sometimes this is because of the new Review queue allowing delete votes at 0, but it may also simply have been upvoted since the delete vote was cast.)
- The question has been undeleted, but is no longer closed so is not a candidate for deletion.

In other words, the greyed-out style  means you cannot cast a delete-vote on it. This is useful and meaningful, and it saves you time.

However, it does not grey it out if you cannot cast a delete/undelete vote ***because you have yourself already done so***.  This wastes a lot of time needlessly running through the delete/undelete dialogue.

I propose that it be changed so that if you have *already* voted to delete (or undelete, where appropriate), it greys out that post to alert you not to bother going through the dialogue again.