# New Review Queue: Deletion Review

Tags: feature-request, review, 10k-tools, vote-to-delete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we get some more review queues - questions with delete votes, recently closed etc.?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148204/can-we-get-some-more-review-queues-questions-with-delete-votes-recently-close)

Should be accessible by everyone with vote to delete rights. It would show posts closed for reasons other than Exact Duplicate that have been inactive (no answers, no edits) for a certain amount of time (6 months, perhaps, TBD). Closed questions are on a road to deletion (unless they are signposts and could help someone find the question with answers), but there's no good way to find and clean up posts that [aren't automatically cleaned up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year).

Alternatively, I suppose that people can be taken out of the process and an automatic process can be applied to closed questions that have been inactive.

Comment: would be helpful to see how this request is different from: [Can we get some more review queues - questions with delete votes, recently closed etc.?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148204/165773) Side note one thing that is _freaking annoying_ about current delete UI is that is shows me posts I already voted on

Comment: @gnat It actually is the same as the "In addition to displaying questions with delete votes the /delete queue could display questions that were closed a long time ago (> 90 days?) and negatively scored ones and haven't been edited recently." paragraph in the one you linked to. I missed that line originally.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is a good idea for low-score posts. There is quite a lot stuff out there that can be safely deleted after some time (often even after a few days since the OP doesn't care about it anymore).

However, I do not think that such a queue should ever show high-score questions or questions with high-score answers - even if those questions are closed an inactive.

The reason for this is that not all old questions which wouldn't be allowed to be posted nowadays have a historic lock on them and while they'd currently never be deleted because most people do not want them deleted a deletion queue would present these questions to exactly those people who think everything closed needs to be deleted even if the majority wants the question to stay and thus there are tons of upvotes on it.

Comment: I read all this in a single breath. Twice over.