# Vote to delete automatically flags

Tags: feature-request, 10k-tools, vote-to-delete, trusted-user

I just hit 20k reputation, thus I'm now able to vote to delete answers.

Now I know there isn't a delete vote queue, so just voting to delete isn't all that reliable, or is it?

So (unless such a queue is created), by assumption, whenever you vote to delete, it would make sense to also flag (but not necessarily vice versa) (correct me if I'm wrong).

Thus, I propose a delete vote causes an automatic flag.

And given that users are given a limited number of delete votes already, these shouldn't count towards your flags. But flags are refunded (aren't they?), so perhaps it should, I don't know. If it does, we can probably get rid of the delete vote limit altogether.

The point is to get the post to [a place where it can be seen](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=flags).

Comment: No real queue like the review queues, but we do have 10K tools, part of them is [View recent delete votes](http://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=today).

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Well, I suppose, but why have different lists for what's essentially the same thing? And is that a 20k only page or is it for everyone (10k)? If the former, that supports my case.

Comment: What exactly is the same thing in your opinion? Looks like I miss your point here. That is part of 10K tools, 10K can't vote to delete answers, only questions and also have a delay until they can vote to delete. (think three days)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd The intention behind a delete vote and a flag are the same (well, not identical, but very similar). Why do the posts go to different places? (I'm primarily talking about *answer* delete flags, that 10k users also handle)

Comment: Flags are cast by low rep users and must not be trusted, many times they use bad judgement so it's essential to have easy way to dispute such flags. Full scale delete votes on the other hand are cast by high rep users who should know what they're doing. There still should be a place to see their actions, but we don't need way to dispute their vote (which is not possible, even for a moderator) - bottom line, having it separate is good in my opinion.

Comment: Related to [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161746).

Answer (score 4):

Pending delete votes are in the 10k tools, which you can reach via review -> tools -> delete.  (Then choose the range; it defaults to "today" but you may want a longer view -- up to 30 days is supported.)

This isn't as convenient or visible as having a real review queue (which I'd like to see), but you can review delete votes and encourage other users with the priv to do so.  I post the link from time to time in chat to remind people.

If you want to also flag a post you are still able to do that, but auto-flagging delete votes would force moderators to deal with flags that the community could handle on their own.  So a human, not an automated system, should decide if it's important enough to do that.