# Time to revise 10k tools Delete and Close pages

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, 10k-tools, information-display

I often go into the 10k tools, into the `delete` and `close` tabs.  I find that I always have to click on one of the links to go the actual question to see if it needs more votes (one way or the other).  A large part of the problem is that there is no information with those one line descriptions except how many votes they have and how many they need (on the `Delete votes` and `Undelete votes` section), as per this snapshot:

[image: Delete Queues]

Some other information that would be nice is:

**1) What time was it posted?**

This would let us know that it's not some good historical question that some deleteist has chosen to purge because it offends his sensibilities.

**2) Does it have any answers?**

If it doesn't have any answers, then there is much more likelihood that it deserves deletion, i.e. nothing useful to be seen here.

**3) What is its score?**

If it has a huge negative score, it probably needs to go away.  If it has a high score it probably needs to stick around.

**4) Did I already vote on this?**

It's pretty irritating to go into a question and vote to open or close and find you've already done that.  Can't we get an indicator (probably color) or a filter for that?

It would really help the usability, allowing me to process things faster, if there was more information on that page.  Currently, I have to click into the question, then hit the back button, then hit the arrow to get the full list, find where I was and look at the next one.  I realize that you would need to go to one-column formatting in this case, but that seems pretty workable.

You could also separate the questions from the answers.

Another thing that would help is having the arrow position persist so I don't have to keep uncollapsing the category.

Possible example of what could be shown:

> A: 1 "NOT IN" subquery with a leading wildcard (2) Score: 0, 21 hours ago
>   Q: 2 "List of lower prime numbers in C# [on hold] (1) Score: -5, 1 hour ago, 0 answers

**How about we give these pages some love?**

Comment: [Showing me stuff I've already voted to delete is pretty much the main reason I don't use this tool.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/189564/147520)

Comment: @Iain Same here.  [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161746/153355).