# Inappropriate closure of question

Tags: support, review, reopen-closed

The closure of [Is "scroll" a valid CSS background attribute for IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12886277/is-scroll-a-valid-css-background-attribute-for-ie) raised my eye brows. Why did this particular question get closed for being "Not constructive"?

This question was proceeded by [a discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12886074/background-property-doesnt-work-in-ie#comments-12886144) (many comments are deleted already) about the validity of the "scroll" value in the `background` CSS property. One of the participants in this discussion casted an (obviously inappropriate) close-as-duplicate vote on the new question.

To my surprise, the question has just been closed for being "Not constructive", even though the initial closure reason is "Exact duplicate". These four close votes were cast by `/review`-ers  with zero knowledge of CSS (judged by looking at `user:XXXX [css]`).

I have already flagged the question for moderator attention, which was deemed helpful. The question is still closed though.

<sub>PS. Where is the **re-open** queue to counter careless `/review` in the Close queue?</sub>

Comment: My first instinct is to close it as "Not a real question"...I mean seriously: `Please confirm that scroll is either a valid, or not valid property of background, and please give me references if possible.` That's at least a big lack of research effort there.

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby He looked up on w3schools, and didn't (want to) understand the (deleted) hints in the comments at the other Q+A. The question was posted after commenting (now deleted) "Okay, stop you two, here's a question to see who's right" (can't remember the exact phrase, but it was something like that).

Comment: _Where is the re-open queue...?_ Feature request is right here: [Add a “Review posts with reopen votes” review task?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/140893/165773)

Comment: So, that's the history of it...but that doesn't change my opinion.

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby: We don't close questions as "Not a real question" for lacking research effort. We close such questions for being unanswerable, lacking sufficient information to answer them, or being too broad. We *downvote* poorly resarched questions, not close them.

Comment: @NicolBolas - Well, I see the research as being key. If you don't tell me what you've done/tried, it's a huge waste of my time to post an answer that... well... tells you something you've already done but failed to tell me about.  I guess that's a slightly different issue than Rob W's example, but I really think context is important for future visitors to determine quickly if a post will help them or not... In this specific example, explaining the problem will tell me why it's important that I care if scroll is standard or not.

Comment: @jmort253: I'm not saying that it's good to not put this stuff in. I'm saying that a question lacking this isn't a valid *close reason*. Would you bother to read a question with -3 votes? Probably not, unless you were just curious. So you still have a signal that a question isn't worth your time. But it's still a real question. Just not a *good* one. We don't close questions for being bad; we close them for being incomplete (missing actual information needed to resolve the issue) or inappropriate.

Comment: @NicolBolas, I'm not sure I agree. If that information is lacking, then it's not useful to future visitors. If it's not useful to future visitors, it doesn't belong.

Answer (score 4):

Not to sound like WSOiN, but Stack Overflow isn't a personal research assistant. :)  This question shows 0 research effort and seems to just demand that the community provide research to this person on the scroll property. The thing that I feel like he's missing is "Hurry, it's urgent!" :)

All joking aside, with that said, I think the question is salvageable. One thing the asker can do to make this sound a little better and justify some reopen votes would be to maybe tell us why he's facing this problem. What research has he done already? Why was MDC and W3Schools not working for him to answer this question? Even saying, "I'm new and don't know where to look" would have been a bit better than insisting we do his research for him.

The reason the context is important is because we learn from people's problems. When a user explains *why* he/she is having a problem, we can relate to it. If we're coming from Google, we can quickly determine if the answers will relate to our problem simply by comparing the problem to ours, if it's similar, then the answers may be similar, if it's not, then the answers may not apply. If the problem is vague, then the post is no better than all the random snapshots of the Internet that are out there on the forums, forcing us to read through stuff that may or may not apply.

In short, I probably would have voted to close too, but I'd also leave comments suggesting some edits, and if the clarifications are made, I'll gladly help reopen. :)  Hope this helps!

Comment: I've edited the question to look less demanding, but am reluctant to add "I'm asking this question because in [this question](link), I answered ...., but others said that I was wrong. I'm confused, what's the correct answer?" About research efforts: Apparently, he [tried to google but was unable to find or understand the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12886277#comment17449518_12886375)). I can imagine where he's coming from; Try to find the right result here, as a CSS noob: https://www.google.com/search?q=css+background+scroll+valid