# Allow first reopen vote to add a reason or hint about adding a comment

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-reopen

I did a few [reopen reviews](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/151618/162730). For some questions it was not at all apparent *why* others wanted to reopen the question. Perhaps it would be nice if the first user casting a reopen vote was asked to (optionally?) add a reason, either similar to a bounty notice or as a regular comment?

Comment: And similar to a downvote for low-rep users: a friendly prompt to comment too.

Comment: It will be reopened for one of two reasons: 1.  It was incorrectly closed, or 2.  It was edited to improve.  Both reasons should be fairly obvious.

Comment: @RobertHarvey -- I agree with your statement above ~90% of the time.  Since users/mods working through the close queue don't even need to be familiar with the language at hand, some questions may seem like a dupe (for example) when in reality they aren't.

Answer (score 1):

Evaluating a question for being re-opened and evaluating a question for being closed are identical. It's just a matter of whether the question meets the criteria for being a valid question on the site you're reviewing for. Each question really should be reviewed independently of any hints, close reasons, etc. We're not racking up votes for the sake of votes, and we certainly don't want to give into the hive mind mentality. If we voted to close something just because someone else did, it wouldn't require five votes, now would it?

If you read the entire question and the comments on it, it should be pretty obvious whether or not it's a good candidate for the site and should be reopened, or if it should remain closed. If you've done that entire read through (not just skimming, mind you) and you still can't decide, either read it again or skip it. Discretion is the better part of valor.

Comment: The only difference being that you can pick "Close Question," and the resulting dialog exposes the close reasons that other users chose.

Comment: Yes, that's true - but I see that as more of a reason for the asker of the question so he doesn't make the same mistake again, not for the other people evaluating the question for closing. I feel we should review it objectively, unbiased by the close reasons given by others.