# Should the reopen queue be available to users with less than 10k rep?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, vote-to-reopen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add a “Review posts with reopen votes” review task?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140893/add-a-review-posts-with-reopen-votes-review-task)

Questions that have a close vote are added to the Close votes queue on the review page. Closed questions are essentially in a 'parked' state awaiting improvement after which they may be opened if editing has improved the quality of the question sufficiently.

Would it make sense to have the +10k reopen queue available to users with enough rep to have close/reopen votes? This would speed up the reopening process for deserving questions.

Comment: FYI: We have a re-open queue, but only for 10K+ users.

Comment: I guess us low-rep users down here wouldn't know about that.

Comment: Related: [Add "Questions edited after closing" review task](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143013)

Comment: @YannisRizos I didn't know about that, thanks for the info. I changed my question slightly to reflect that.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39420/why-is-10-000-rep-needed-to-access-moderation-tools

Answer (score 2):

There is already a 'reopen queue', available to 10K+ users. You can view it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?s=1&tab=close&daterange=), and it looks something like this:

[image: Review Queue Screenshot]

As you can see, there are arrows next to both lists that let you expand and see more if you'd like. You can also sort them by closing.

I'm not entirely sure that opening this up to users lower than 10K is worthwhile though. It's a difficult list to navigate through, unlike the close queue, so it should be used with care.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I edited my question to reflect a comment with this information. I think it would be worthwhile opening this queue to users with close/reopen votes to give reopening a bit more emphasis. I'm sure the queue could be made a bit more user friendly if this was implemented. I also found a [duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140893/add-a-review-posts-with-reopen-votes-review-task?rq=1) which I missed when searching before I posted my question.

Comment: I'd rather see the reopen queue implemented to replace this crappy "tools" thing. I have honestly *never* used that particular page.

Comment: @animuson oh for sure. But some of the statistics given by that page are invaluable, and shouldn't be taken lightly