# Something Bad Happened on the moderator tools privilege page

Tags: bug, status-completed, privileges

Trying to go to the moderator tool privilege page:

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools

Causes an error:

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/privileges/moderator-tools

This also is causing the same error on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools) and on [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools), but not on any of the other sites in the Trilogy or Stack Exchange 2.0, beta or graduated.

Also, while you're fixing it for Gaming, notice that [that page shows wrong information anyway](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1370/the-moderator-tools-privilege-page-still-lists-2000-rep-as-the-threshold).

Comment: Actually is happening on [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools) as well. I think it's a global thing.

Comment: @Grace doesn't happen on SO itself, though, so not entirely global.

Comment: I'm not 10k, but it happens for me too

Comment: @Earlz viewing the privilege page doesn't require any reputation, so I wouldn't expect this to change based on who the viewer is.

Comment: @Grace thanks for the migration and the updates :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just fixed this will be deployed later today!

Comment: Since when did waffles become a developer?

Comment: @Earlz - if only we could [differentiate between employees and moderators](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77883/differentiate-between-employees-and-moderators)…

Comment: @Earlz On [June 25th, 2010](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/welcome-stack-overflow-valued-associate-00008/). Or at least, that's the announcement. So give or take a couple of days.