# Use a different symbol to delineate Team Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Differentiate between employees and moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77883/differentiate-between-employees-and-moderators)

Site Moderators get a little ♦ next to their name to, well, indicate that they're Moderators.

Members of the Stack Overflow team get the same symbol next to their names as well. (I guess if they choose to also moderate that site.)

I think it'd be nice for Team SO to have a different symbol. ♠ perhaps.

Comment: Wow, 23 upvotes for the duplicate? I might give this a pity upvote now

Comment: Searched. Didn't find. Voting to close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Members of the Stack Overflow team used to have stars ★ as their designation.  'Owners' of SE 1.0 sites had double diamonds. ♦♦. The people appointed to moderate by them were single diamond moderators ♦. The single diamond moderator is the only symbol still in use.

The fact that they make them all one diamond keeps there from being a class division between the two. Perhaps it's the team's way of saying that diamond moderators should be trusted by the community as much as the team?

Comment: I thought the double diamonds were only for 'administrators' of SE 1.0 sites.

Comment: I was going to post this exact feature request a while ago, and your second paragraph is the reason I didn't; I decided it's kind of nice that devs look the same as mods, and nearly all users don't even know the distinction

Comment: Pretty sure @jjnguy is right. The original symbol for the team was a star, which changed to a diamond shortly after Marc and Bill were elected. I know it was still a star as late as May 2009.

Comment: @jjnguy you're absolutely right. I'd forgotten about the stars.

Comment: @George Stocker, still not *quite* right. SE 1.0 sites had two different classes of moderator: the two-diamond administrators and the one-diamond moderators, appointed by the administrators. This, I suppose, was because nobody on SE 1.0 sites could set or unset people as moderators just by changing a field in the database. See http://mathoverflow.net/users?page=1 and http://mathoverflow.net/users?page=2 for examples.

Comment: @mmyers thanks for clearing that up; I don't remember seeing single diamond moderators on the SE1.0 sites; but I don't really remember much from back then.

Comment: @George, I don't think all SE 1.0 site owners chose to appoint mods, but they did have the option, as proven [here](http://testing.stackexchange.com/users). Good answer!

Answer (score 1):

If:

1. They have different abilities
2. It's important for users to understand that the action was taken by an Employee specifically (ie, not just a mod, and not just an employee acting as a mod, but a capital E Employee)

The first may be true for some employee/mods (though I doubt that every employee is a mod, nevermind has more access than a mod, though certainly several do).

However, I don't think that the second is true.

Comment: They do have different abilities, and I think that's the more important point; you need to know if a user is even capable of doing what you ask (e.g. people frequently ask mods to fix meta/main account linking, when mods can't do that; you need a dev). However, the few people that are even aware of the difference probably also know which users are devs and which aren't

Comment: @Michael - Not all employees will know how to, or have the ability to, link accounts either.