# Could we have a list of staff moderators in addition to the community moderators?

Tags: feature-request, moderators, tour

The `/about` page (like https://meta.stackoverflow.com/about) at the bottom lists all the community ♦ moderators (elected or appointed - or none at all for new sites still in private beta).

In addition, there are ♦ moderators from the [Staff Exchange staff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77883/differentiate-between-employees-and-moderators) on each site (like [Jeff](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood), the [community coordinators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-coordinators-and-what-do-they-do), and likely some developers, too), but their existence and role is not evident from this page.

My suggestion: The about page for each Stack Exchange site should either contain a list of these *staff moderators* (it should not be too hard to generate this list - the engine has to know who they are anyways), or at least a link to some other place where they are listed (if the list is the same for all the sites - I'm not sure about this), with a sentence about their role.

Answer (score 4):

https://stackexchange.com/about/team

Comment: Linking this from the about pages seems like a good start (though not all of them have even an account linked, and not all of those are moderators).

Comment: @Paulo I agree that it would be nice to call out all those with moderator power on the individual site page.  But this at least gives you what you need right now.

Comment: Yes, thanks. (I upvoted, but I will not yet accept it.)