# Give moderators per-site "badges" in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, moderators

This isn't for "badges" in the "achievements" sense as it is commonly seen here.  This is for the "identification" type of badge.

This idea occcured to me when I first visited [The Assembly](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2691/the-assembly).  Since this is a chat room specifically created for users of all StackExchange sites to have easy access and visibility to moderators from all over the SE network, I figured it would be good if there was an easy way to figure out who's who in the room.

The diamonds are a good indicator of who *has* moderator powers.  But, in a room full of moderators from all over, it would be more useful to know *where* they have the moderator powers.

Most users have their primary site tagged in their chat profile, and most moderators also have mention of the sites that they moderate.  However, there's a few problems with this, all really stemming from one:

1. These are user-defined options.

- [They cannot be relied upon to be accurate.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3709466#3709466)
  [image]
- [They are not necessarily uniform.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3709440#3709440)
- [In some cases, they may not be defined at all.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3709485#3709485)

What I'm suggesting here is that there be another section put into the chat profile, preferably near the top, so that users can see who moderates where.  This should be fairly prominent and visible when a user clicks on a moderator's icon in chat.  It should also be automatically populated by the system, or manually by SEI as part of conferring moderator status to a user.  This can be done by a simple text list, or by badge-like icons.

We've already had [a short discussion about this in The Assembly](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2691/conversation/moderators-site-lists).

Tangentially related:  [Differentiate between employees and moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77883/152399)

---

EDIT:

As @kiamlaluno has mentioned, and I've also touched on, the linking of one's primary site to their chat profile is a necessary part of becoming a moderator.  This gives a fair indication of where one moderates by putting the site icon and a link to their site profile in their chat profile.  However, there's still a not-insignificant percentage of moderators who handle multiple sites and would not be fully served by the existing system.

In all, we have 23 out of 272 moderators who are multi-site mods.  That is excluding those who inherit their MSO moderator rights from being moderators on SO.  This translates to about 8.46% or a little better than one in twelve.

Comment: +1 for "moderator on iszi.stackexchange.com".

Comment: For clarity sake, how about "shields" instead of "badges"?

Comment: Note that moderator names appear in blue whereas regular users are in black, so you can't *entirely* fake being a mod just by throwing stuff into your "About Me". :) Also, moderators have to set their parent site to be a site they're mods at in order to get access to the not-so-secret mod chatroom, so you can often figure out where they mod based on that. Of course that doesn't quite work for people who moderate multiple sites.

Comment: +1 to @AnnaLear for "that doesn't quite work for people who moderate multiple sites".  I know the moderator names are different, and I can't exactly fake a diamond either.  It was more for the sake of amusement than anything, and to demonstrate that one point.

Comment: @AnnaLear - are you talking about me? :)

Comment: @John I think I'm going to leave it as "badges" just because I'm really not even sure what form this would end up taking.  It could be shields, it could be labels, it could be a combination thereof.

Comment: @ChrisF You, Ivo Flipse, Pat Ludwig, studiohack, Gilles, and several others I'm sure.

Comment: Just memorize all the names. It's only a couple of hundred. Sure, it's a minimal barrier to entry, but this is a for-experts site.

Comment: Current numbers look like 35/331 (removing MSO from users who also have SO).  Seems to be sticking roughly around the 1/10 moderators mark.

Answer (score 3):

Moderators are already instructed to associate their chat account with the site where they are moderators. This is required for them to access a private chat room for moderators.

As such, the information you are requiring is already reported in the chat account of a moderator.

[image: screenshot]

In the case a moderator is moderating more than one site, deciding which account associate with the chat account is up to the moderator; normally, the associated account is for the site where the moderator is more active.

Comment: This still does not address the problem I've pointed out.  That it relies upon user-defined options means that it cannot be relied upon to be accurate, uniform, or in some cases present at all.  This is *especially* the case for multi-site moderators.  And, as noted in my comment, there's *plenty* of those.

Comment: @Iszi The user isn't a chat mod unless their account is associated with the site they're a mod on, so if they show up as a diamond, that icon is the site they're a mod on. They might be a mod on another site, but those users are rare. The icon is always there, in the same place; I don't know why you're saying it's not accurate, uniform, or present -- it's all of those things

Comment: The primary site icon, I'll give you.  But we've already identified five fairly prominent cross-site moderators, so I wouldn't say that those are exactly rare.  Just those five alone represent over 2% of the moderator population, and I'm sure there's plenty more.

Comment: By my count there are currently 35 moderators who are diamonds on more than one site, but that includes people who moderate both SO and MSO (others metas don't count as separate sites, FWIW).

Comment: @AnnaLear So, using some really rough math, that's about 16% of the moderator population affected.  In other words, nearly one in six moderators are multi-site moderators.  Some adjustments to affect that percentage would be:  Remove MSO/SO mods from counting as multi-mods, unless they also moderate other sites (reduction).  Account for sites with more than the usual 3 moderators (probable reduction).  Adjust to account for multi-mods that cover more than two sites (increase).  Maybe someone at [math.se] or [statistics.se] can give us a more accurate estimate.

Comment: Correction:  Since MSO Mods == SO Mods, removing those from the count would actually increase the percentage, because you're removing a *lot* of moderator slots from the overall tally.  Maybe if I get bored later tonight, I'll go through the mods lists and figure out the exact numbers.

Comment: @Iszi MSO mods == SO Mods is almost true. All SO mods are MSO mods, but not all MSO mods are SO mods (for historical reasons). If you want to math it out yourself, you may find http://stackexchange.com/about/moderators helpful.

Comment: @AnnaLear Went through the list and did the real math.  See my question edit.

Comment: @AnnaLear What is that number like now? I know I've gotten my second diamond since 5/12...

Comment: @C.Ross I've no idea. You can calculate them from the http://stackexchange.com/about/moderators page. :)