# User without a diamond added a moderator-only-tag

Tags: support, moderator-abilities, moderator-tags

See [this revision list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/152873/revisions). Jason (who is a diamond moderator) added [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag then half hour later changed to [status-reproduced](/questions/tagged/status-reproduced) removing the the status-completed tag, probably after realizing it was not yet fixed.

16 hours passed, and [this user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/168353/mythz) (who does not have any diamond) added the status-completed again:

> [image]

Quick look in his [main account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/85785/mythz) revealed he is Stack Exchange employee but still, I was under the impression that *diamond = moderator powers*.

So, can moderator status be applied without diamond? Or certain users can get certain powers?

Comment: Seeing as this user _fixed_ the issue, I am assuming the user is a _dev_ though not a moderator.

Comment: @Oded as far as I know even Stack Exchange employees need the diamond to have moderator powers.. but maybe I was mistaken.

Comment: Well... if you have access to the DB and can run SQL directly ;)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd There seem to be various levels of access for SE employees, not all employees have access to all features. I'm not surprised that those features don't seem to be directly connected to the diamond.

Comment: @MadScientist agreed, would be nice to have it finally explained then. :)

Comment: It would also be nice that employees were indicated as such

Comment: @Chris you mean some other character, or different color for the diamond? Think I saw such request here in the past but don't think it's really necessary. Having proper "About me" in their profile is fine, but if they also have mod powers then this should be visible.

Comment: What about one of this Chars: ◇ (U+25C7) or ◆ (U+25C6) or even ◈ (U+25C8). Maybe even several of them (Employee, Employee + Mod...)

Comment: @JohannesKuhn it was discussed in depth [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77883/152859) and declined, nothing more we can do.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Thanks for the link, didn't know that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you check other actions taken by this user (e.g. [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/153116/revisions) or [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/129297/revisions)), it will be rather safe to assume that this user is one of the developers (probably responsible for the features/bugs mentioned in the questions).

Comment: Yes indeed, changed my question. Considering even changing to feature-request, asking to always show diamond for those with mod powers but waiting for some official response first.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd As far as I am aware developers don't have to be moderators, and can actually choose which sites to have diamonds on. I do remember it looking confusing in the moderator stats if they are since they often don't do normal moderation tasks but still get tracked.