# Are there moderators without a diamond?

Tags: discussion, moderators

I'm not so sure what moderators are, but I know they are separated from other users by a diamond. I thought moderators are employees but from time to time I see someone without a diamond near his name who says something like this:

> We have .....

Which conveys that he is a stackexchange employer.  Here is my question:

Are there moderators without a diamond?

Comment: No, most moderators are volunteers, elected by the community.

Comment: Even users who are not affiliated with the company sometimes use "we" when they refer to Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange. That's because the community is very invested in the place, has ownership of the content through the CC license, and plays some role in the decision-making process.

Comment: Regarding " We have .....", high rep users can vote to close and vote to delete

Comment: You're looking too far into the "we" thing. When referring to my favorite sports teams I use "we" but clearly I'm not ACTUALLY on the team (that's what I want you to think! I'm actually Von Miller.).

Comment: @Martijn the question you referred to doesn't answer: are there moderators without a diamond? Which is the main reason I asked the question.

Comment: @user689: The community is expected to self-moderate, to a certain extend. The more reputation you gain, the more options you have to help moderate the site. So you could say that higher-reputation users are (limited) moderators too. But generally speaking, the term 'moderator' refers to the diamond moderators. There are no moderators with the same powers that do *not* have a diamond next to their name.

Comment: @user689 This is the danger of asking multiple questions at once. Try to ask one at a time

Comment: @user689 You shouldn't keep editing the question simply to ask what is affectively another question. Just ask a new one, first searching to make sure it's not already asked, of course. People take time to review and vote as dupe, then if it should be reopened.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Are all stackexchange employers moderators?

No.  Only certain employees are diamond (the dev / community types most often).  Others (like [SamtheBrand](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/39006/samthebrand) while an employee doesn't have a diamond... he doesn't even have 2k rep to get his edits automatic) aren't.  Only employees that actually *need* the diamond have it.

From else-meta [Can we give the community evangelist something more notable to make suggested edits go more smoothy?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6200/can-we-give-the-community-evangelist-something-more-notable-to-make-suggested-ed) from the esteemed Anna:

> Most employees don't require special privileges across the network. Heck, many of us aren't really using the sites and/or aren't always in tune with how individual communities work. Those of us who do have network-wide diamonds take great care to avoid abusing them or overstepping any bounds when it comes to site-specific privileges.

> Are all moderators employers?

No.  Very few moderators are employees.  The vast majority are volunteers that the community has entrusted.

> Are there moderators without a diamond?

Not really.  The *community* moderates with close votes and delete votes.  Diamond mods just do it without needing more because of the above mentioned entrustment.

Comment: What do you mean by employees that *need* the diamond?

Comment: evelopers (who need to be able to poke the database correctly) and community managers (who are in tune with communities and need to be able to be a mod if need be) are the only ones that I've seen. Not all the other employees need a diamond. I've linked a discussion else-meta about having one employee with only ~200 rep (no diamond) be able to bypass /review for edits (he wasn't and isn't, and shouldn't - but it was a question if he *should*) where this was clarified a bit.

Comment: Wait, I thought I read something somewhere about all employees having the option to carry diamonds if they want to?

Comment: @Undo I haven't seen that mentioned or referenced anywhere.  Its *possible*, I don't know the internal policies of SE and at the same time, I've seen employees without.  Getting a diamond can be like "do you want to have a broom so you can be a volunteer janitor too?" with the expectation that they *will* be able to use it if needed.  As a (not SE) dev, I'd rather stay as far away from root-esq production access as I can.

Answer (score 6):

> Are all stackexchange employers moderators?

I thought so too, but apparently not. The Valued Associates and Community managers are all diamond mods, but some developers or lower-level employees may not be

> Are all moderators employers?

No, there are plenty of community-elected moderators for every site who are unpaid

> Are there moderators without a diamond?

If you have >10k rep, you have access to many moderator tools. They are called 10K mods

Also, you say that people say `we have...`

That's just because they are members of the SE community just like us, and so they use "we" to mean Stack Exchange in general, just like people refer to their favorite sports team as "we", even though they don't play for that team.

Comment: There are also employees without a diamond who can still perform moderator only action, see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/154882/152859).

Comment: @ShadowWizard devs are technically higher than diamond mods if they can access the database, but they still have to agree to the same terms that a diamond mod has to beforehand (mostly the privacy policy)

Comment: @Santa I was referring to their privileges, which aren't strictly related to having or not having a diamond.

Comment: @ShadowWizard there's two diamond classes: "Moderator" and "Stack Exchange Employee". The diamond-less mods are devs

Comment: If you're an employee and you need a diamond (moderator rights) to do your job, you get one. If you're working on the core software that runs these sites, you get a superset of moderator rights by default, since they include a lot of tools you'll need to fix and monitor things. Otherwise, you have access to a handful of things normal users don't (mostly internal tools) and beyond that *are* a normal user.