# Do community managers vote on questions/answers?

Tags: discussion, support, community-managers

A while ago, there was some drama on a meta site, and a user said something along the lines of the following (I'm going to paraphrase it because I'm not trying to dig up old drama):

> The Stack Exchange employees are downvoting my post because they don't like it.

Which made me wonder: do Community Managers vote on posts at all? In particular, do they downvote posts in meta arguments?

Comment: Assuming they've earned the privilege to downvote on the specific site, why wouldn't they?

Comment: @Yannis conflict of interest? To clarify, I'm only asking this because I'm curious: whether or not they vote on posts won't effect my opinion of the community managers.

Comment: How is it a conflict of interest? Some ideas are bad. Some can't be easily implemented. Some have been discussed to death. Some just don't fit the way the CM thinks things should work. I expect the CMs to have opinions on many meta posts and from their experience, I'd guess many of those don't agree with what others think.

Comment: @Yannis actually I suspect that even 1 rep user with a diamond (or SE employee powers) can vote as well. Know for sure that [SE employees without diamond can use mod-only tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154882/user-without-a-diamond-added-a-moderator-only-tag), so this is likely the same. :)

Comment: @Hamlet _"The Stack Exchange employees are downvoting ..."_ I'd suspect a silly misconception of the OP stating so, how could they know who was downvoting their question? I've often seen (particularly new) OPs thinking the community members with higher rep are SE moderators or employees.

Comment: Moderators vote on meta questions about moderation policies; is that a conflict of interest?  Users whose questions are being discussed on meta vote on those posts; is that a conflict of interest?  CMs are still site users, and if they've earned the downvote privilege, why shouldn't they be allowed to use it?

Comment: @MonicaCellio Technicality: the clause "if they've earned" does not apply, because a diamond confers all user privileges, regardless of reputation. E.g., a [CM with 101 points from association bonus](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users/8604/shog9?tab=topactivity) can downvote.

Answer (score 17):

They definitely vote on posts. If you take any of [the Community Managers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99341/229438) and look at their "Votes Cast" table, you'll see that they do vote - also downvotes on Meta posts.

Answer (score 17):

Believe it or not, but Stack Exchange employees, no matter their role, are also humans. They have their own opinions, and they have interest in Stack Exchange beyond the fact they work in there.

There is no line in their contract saying "you must not vote on Stack Exchange site".

So yes, they vote.

Consider this as having two hats: one is the employee hat, and one the personal, ordinary person, hat.

I have full confidence that no Stack Exchange employee is abusing his powers or have any personal agenda against specific users. They're better than that, and it's really not worth risking their careers for such things.

Comment: They only have two hats?

Comment: "Stack Exchange employees are humans" -- Mmhmm, that's what they *want* you to think.

Comment: @Simon yup, but they get to keep them all year long, not just during the Bash of Winter. :-D

Comment: @JasonC and to think you want to be one of them... now it all makes sense! ;-)

Comment: +1 for Believe it or not,.. are also humans !!

Comment: You misspelled Unicorns ...

Answer (score 13):

One person, one vote. Not only are Community Managers also "normal users" of the system with opinions and thoughts of their own, but most of us were hired directly from the community's top regular users. They are also subject to the majority of system checks and balances that catch things like voting fraud or other potential abuses that would be flagged or undone by the system… just like "regular" users.

Comment: I am wondering? can they see who voted what?

Comment: Excellent points, especially the "subject to the majority of system checks" which is really not obvious. Kudos! :)

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis No they (the OP  who made the statement) can't see who was voting. See my comment on the question.

Comment: We have access to the raw data, so we *could* determine this, @πάνταῥεῖ... But under normal circumstances, this would be an incredibly bad idea, and all of the normal tools we use hide this information. (even excluding everyone else, can you imagine how uncomfortable it'd be if you saw that your *co-workers* were downvoting your post?)

Comment: @Shog9 I'm not sure we misunderstood here. I meant the OP that made the original statement mentioned in the question can't see who downvoted their question (that's true, not?). Thus I suspect they made a silly assumption, who was downvoting, and these people must have been community moderators. Sure it's a good thing that votes are strictly anonymous for most of the users here. (My co-workers would tell me directly, I'd at least expect them to do so actually ;-) ).

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis they can, but on their own posts this is disabled.