# Whose votes on what are binding?

Tags: support, binding-vote

There are a lot of kinds of votes. Some are binding (i.e., only 1 single vote is required to incur the related result) while some require more votes to be confirmed. Is there a category about what votes are "binding"?

Comment: AFAICT, OP's review vote on suggested edits on his own posts are binding. All ♦ votes are binding (one exception). Anything else?

Comment: Um, I think it's just the mods and the OP. Probably not worth making a list, which could explain the downvote, although it's not mine.

Comment: Using a search like this https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=binding%20vote and reviewing the returned Q&As should put you well on the way to writing an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following are considered binding votes:

- Diamond moderators: binding vote for everything on sites they moderate. (close/reopen/delete/undelete/review)
- Post author:

  - For questions, binding delete vote as long as there is no answer with an upvote, or multiple answers that have no votes.
  - For answers, binding delete vote as long as the answer is not accepted.
  - For both questions and answers: author has binding undelete vote if the post was deleted by the author.
  - Review: post authors have binding vote when reviewing a suggested edit on the post.
  - For comments: the comment author has binding delete vote for the comment, but worth to keep in mind this can't be undone, unlike posts that can be undeleted.
  - All other votes are not binding.
- Users with a gold tag badge: Binding close or reopen votes, but only when voting to close or reopen a question that has that tag, and only when voting to close/reopen as a duplicate. (as long as they didn't add that tag themselves to the question)

Comment: Users with gold tag badge **can't** cast a binding vote if they have ever edited the tags of the question they're voting.

Comment: @iDebug thanks, edited

Comment: I wonder if the "improve edit/reject and edit" and "agree to close own post as duplicate" actions count here. Technically the votes are from Community, then.

Comment: @muru thought about it, and yes, those aren't really direct votes.

Comment: I don't think SE employees get moderator powers without a visible diamond (if you ignore a developer directly modifying the DB). The only exception I can think of was the CHAOS team, and they only had a limited power for a short time.

Comment: @MadScientist they do get, see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154882/user-without-a-diamond-added-a-moderator-only-tag). I'm pretty sure they can do more than just add moderator tags, and it was not a CHAOS member as far as I can tell.

Comment: According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/74471/349538), the OP can only delete their own question if the answer doesn't have any upvotes, no matter the number of downvotes. So a question with one answer with 1 upvote and 10 downvotes can't be deleted by the OP. I don't think that's good, but that's the way it is.

Comment: @DonaldDuck interesting, I always assumed positive score, not just upvote but guess I was wrong.

Comment: [meta-tag:community-user] has a binding close vote for duplicates that are confirmed by asker (["This solved my problem"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250930/165773))

Comment: @gnat That doesn't worth pointing out as the Community user is a ♦.

Comment: @gnat also, Community is not really a user, the question here is about actual users and their binding votes.

Comment: You're missing binding undelete votes. Post authors get them if they were the only one to delete their post but I'm not sure what other situations. The OP used to be able to reverse a deletion from review but this may have been fixed.

Comment: @Laurel thanks, edited with that I know, was also missing comments. :)

Comment: Diamond moderators do *not* have binding votes for *everything* on the sites they moderate: The exception is their vote in moderator elections. :-)