# Why is information about triage and help and improvement review queues there in help centers of non-SO sites?

Tags: discussion, review, help-center

In the *What are review queues?* help center articles of non-Stack Overflow sites, there is some information about triage and help and improvement review queues.

> - [Triage](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-triage) – Stack Overflow only - 500 reputation. The primary goal of Triage is to quickly sort questions into groups: good as is, needs community editing, or should be closed/flagged.
> - [Help and improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-help-and-improvement) - Stack Overflow only - 2,000 reputation. This queue lets you edit questions that were flagged in Triage as needing community editing.

Since the aforementioned review queues are specific to Stack Overflow, I don't understand why the above quoted information exists in non-Stack Overflow sites' help center.

Why does this information exist in help centers of non-Stack Overflow sites? Shouldn't it be removed?

Comment: Because the help center is shared across all sites except two pages that can be edited by moderators.

Comment: @rene What are the two pages?

Comment: on-topic and the blurb on the /help under the search box

Comment: @rene So, I think the help center articles across all SE sites can be changed as these review queues are irrelevant to SE sites.

Comment: No, there is one code base all sites run on.  Those review queues are available on all sites, just not enabled. if anything, the text could be changed: `s/Stack Overflow only/(when enabled)/`

Comment: @rene Can you please share the source of your information?

Comment: I might be blurry but you have to take my word for it. I'm sure a CM is happy to write an answer here.

Comment: Random, according to the announcement it would [only appear on SO's Help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356120/creating-new-help-center-documents-for-review-queues-project-overview/356141); the announcement *claims* that help for the Triage and H&I wouldn't appear on non-SO help pages.

Comment: @Rob the full articles lead to a 404, for example here on MSE for [Triage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/review-triage). The blurps quoted above, however do show up on [Reviews-intro](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/reviews-intro).

Comment: @Luu JG & Spe have discussed this in The Tavern; may be fixed in a day or two.

Answer (score 9):

> Why does this information exist in help centers of non-Stack Overflow sites?

Because that page is a static page, which is similar on all sites. Having this the same across all sites probably makes for easier maintenance of the help center pages.

> Shouldn't it be removed?

In my opinion, no, it doesn't need removing. It's clearly labelled 'Stack Overflow only' and it's not drowning out any other information.

Additionally, having these queues explained the way they are is a good way of introducing them to people that might never encounter them on Stack Overflow, but who may encounter avid SO users in chatrooms. Saves a bit of confusion if you know that there are SO only queues if they come up in conversation.

Comment: IMO relevant information in help centers matter more than *"easier maintenance of the help center pages"*. *"having these queues explained the way they are is a good way of introducing them to people that might never encounter them on Stack Overflow, but who may encounter avid SO users in chatrooms."* I think that is applicable to a very minor percentage of users.

Comment: @RandomPerson I'm glad my answer helped you come up with some arguments for removing this information, since your question until now was totally lacking any argument that they *should* be removed! For the rest, it's probably a waste of my time to argue what is/isn't "relevant information" with someone that already seems to have made up their mind that this information is irrelevant. It's not unusual for SE to stuff that's applicable to a very minor percentage of users either, like having an ability to add image descriptions while only a minor percentage of users needs those too.

Comment: Image descriptions are not the right things to compare with in this scenario. Image description is for accessibility whereas help center articles are resources for learning more about the site. If I'm not wrong, help center articles are meant to be precise and not lengthy. The counter-argument would be it's just a few extra lines. I have an alternate suggestion. Why not place the SO review queues at the end and give more preference to the site's review queues? I know the reviews queues are ordered according to reputation, but we can bend the rules.

Comment: "Why not place the SO review queues at the end and give more preference to the site's review queues?" – I've made an edit to the `/help/reviews-intro` (network-wide) Help Center page to do exactly this. ...Well, technically, I've reorganized the review queues into the order they now appear in in the dropdown on Stack Overflow; per [this answer on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/346651/1478931), they're ordered first by the minimum reputation needed to access the queue, and then alphabetically by the name of the queue. Conveniently, that also puts Triage at the end.