# Draggable window can go outside of the page content

Tags: bug, status-declined

The draggable window can go to the outside of the page content. See the screen shot bellow:

> [image]

It's a minor issue, but better to be known. :-)

Comment: Solution: Don't do that.

Comment: @Oded Yes, I said that it's minor. Some CSS would solve the problem.

Comment: I don't see a problem.

Comment: I actually like it so I can get the window right out of the way.

Comment: @PeterJ - Indeed, that's the whole point of making it draggable. So it can be out of the way.

Comment: @Johnツ this "bug" also exist in Windows, if you drag windows around you can do [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pSbGm.png).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you don't want the draggable window to go outside the window bounds, don't drag it there.

Comment: Ok, if the moderator says that I accept the idea. :-) Thanks!

Comment: @Johnツ - Correction, a dev is saying that, not a moderator ;)

Comment: @Oded: To make this distinction, perhaps devs should have *two* diamonds (just to make everyone else feel inferior). ;-)

Comment: @Jamal - All devs will say that on their profile. But yes, having some sort of easy visual distinction is not a bad idea which has come up before (at least in regards to SE staff vs mods).

Comment: @Oded: I did see that.  I'm also okay with checking each profile (and possibly memorizing who's who).

Comment: @Oded how about [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zItbl.png)? ;)

Comment: `<3` would be better, @Sha ;)

Comment: @Oded go ahead then and add it! :P

Comment: @Jamal [Differentiate between employees and moderators](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77883/differentiate-between-employees-and-moderators) has been proposed in the past and was marked as [meta-tag:status-declined].

Comment: @psubsee2003 decline is far from being final. Most famous and recent case it [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/915/152859): declind by Jeff himself back in 2009 and now completed to the happiness of us all. :)

Comment: @psubsee2003: Those are some fair arguments.  *But*, I still don't see the problem with using <3.  It only shows that the mods/devs still love us plebs!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd & Jamal I know, that's what inspired me to offer a bounty to hopefully bring new attention there.  I think this is needed on MSO more so than other sites.