# Is there a page that allows mere mortals to know who actually works for Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, stack-exchange-team

So, there are mods, and there are Mods - by which 1 mean the 101 diamonds / actual Stack Exchange employees who have access to the devs, etc.

By <strike>playing around</strike> regular input and activity on the various sites, I think I know many of the actual SE staff (Shog, Adam Lear, Jon Ericson, Marc Gravell, etc.), but is there a page where I can see all of them?

In some ways it would be really nice just to be able to see their interests and be able to quickly differentiate, say, Shog9's input from <insert your least favorite troll here>.  Ideally, this would be a 'flair page' meaning that the staff directory would show the name, function, and reputation of each individual on staff.

I realize this may be mere voyuerism on my part, but it is still nice to know the players. More importantly, if someone hits the 'contact us' link, it would be nice to know who is answering. (Yes, it's probably Adam or Shog, but again...)

Comment: Shog9 *is* my least favorite troll.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the Community Managers in particular, there's a [list of them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-managers-and-what-do-they-do) here on Meta.

There was a request to [differentiate employees on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77883/differentiate-between-employees-and-moderators) (and other sites), but it was [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).

Comment: Yes, but it shows their real names, not their user accounts.

Comment: @AffableGeek Click on them.

Comment: Aha!  Yeah, that's no so obvious.  (It took me a long time to find out that Josh Heyer is Shog.)  But, it works.  Thanks!

Comment: @AffableGeek All of us also have *something* in our site profiles to indicate that we're employees.

Comment: mostly i was looking to go the other way - i know your handle, but not your real name.  Just my hangup - i usually like to know the real person (says the guy with the handle and a picture of his kids as his avatar...)

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, @Affable, I don't know Anna's real name either.

Comment: Should this be updated because of https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/331682/399694 adding this?