# Do staff that leave SE still participate in the community or do they just keep their rep/status and become regular users?

Tags: discussion, reputation, stack-exchange-team

I've seen a couple of Farewell posts. Do staff with high or low rep keep it after they leave the company as a status/symbol, or do they come back as regular users and just help the community?

Comment: Staff that leave SE are finally set free and can do whatever they want. Most of them do.

Comment: Note that companies have two exits: A front door and a back door. It matters which door you (had to) use to leave.

Comment: People aren't homogeneous. The amount which individuals participated in the community varied both prior to being hired and while employees. How much each person participates after leaving employment is going to be (mostly) up to them (as long as SE doesn't prevent them from doing so for some unusual reason). Why do you think there might be a uniform answer to this for all past employees?

Comment: Hi @Makyen Thanks for the reply. I know some companies when you leave them you can't access anything that was the companies. just figured since SE was the company and they got rep from them while being part of the community that the possibly had to start over or something. I was just wondering.

Comment: @BigJoe The vast majority of SO employees don't participate on the network as a direct part of their job function. There are some, primarily Community Managers, who do. For those people, the vast majority of the company business posts which they make which also gain them reputation are here on Meta Stack Exchange. What each person does appears to be up to the individual. There are definitely some people who participated quite a bit and kept using their accounts after leaving the company. There are others who haven't been heard from again (yet?).

Comment: Thanks @Makyen I was wondering why some of the staff post aren't technical, more of announcements etc..

Comment: IMO the question is quite clear: do former employees keep their accounts and reputation? Answer: yes. Some of them also keep _using_ their account to share their opinions on Meta after they have left, others don't post anymore. Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347859/we-need-a-former-staff-account-flag

Comment: Thanks @Marijn  that was a really good related post. Curious how did you find that? I did a search but didn't find that one. It's actually quite good.

Comment: @BigJoe I remembered it from reading it before when it was first posted in 2020. When you are on Meta a bit longer then more and more topics will 'click together' :)

Comment: @rene not really. Surely not "most". Maybe a few. Actually, I can't point even a single staff member who left SE and still active here. Posting something once every few months (e.g. Jon, Shog) is not considered "active". Still better than the vast majority who just leave without a trace.

Comment: @BigJoe also worth to mention, there was single case of ex-staff who kept his diamond even after leaving (and not as moderator), that being Jeff Atwood, the co-founder of Stack Overflow. He had diamond on all sites for many years after leaving, until management was replaced and put an end to this.

Comment: Related: *[2023 Layoff impacting 58 SO/SE staff (2023-05-10)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389060/2023-layoff-impacting-58-so-se-staff-2023-05-10/389061#389061)*

Answer (score 7):

In as much as [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347859/we-need-a-former-staff-account-flag), suggested by [Marijn in the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389522/do-staff-that-leave-se-still-participate-in-the-community-or-do-they-just-keep-t#comment1298973_389522), doesn't answer your question (they are technically not duplicates, IMHO): yes, former employees (e.g. [Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9), [Pops](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/131713/pops), [Oded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/140505/oded)) can keep the reputation they garnered from before and during their employment.
They become regular users, in the sense that on paper they don't have any elevated position. Of course, their reputation (expressed in the amount of both points and name recognition) is often of such a calibre that their interactions wield a certain authority.

To answer the question whether former employees still participate on the network: that is completely up to them.

Answer (score 5):

I would say it very much depends. Many staff *never* participate in the community, nor need to in the course of their work. And the actual level of participation varies hugely, and frankly if someone left due to a downsizing, or in some other less happy way - I wouldn't blame them.

Fundamentally - its really difficult to stay engaged with an organization that doesn't really appreciate your work. Sometimes the communities make it 'worth' it - but even then, the energy to do so's a lot less than it used to be.

Its also worth remembering, outside the moderation and community management tooling (as needed) , there's nothing 'special' about a staff tag and some might even participate as regular users in theory.

So they do keep their accounts and reputation if they are no longer with the company - how much they participates depends on them.