# "We are currently offline for maintenance", but we're not

Tags: support, maintenance

Are there any on-going issues right now with SE infrastructure?

Both chat and sites have been experiencing intermittent issues for a few hours. This has been reported on Stack Overflow (main, meta and chat), as well as multiple *.stackexchange sites.

I'd put this down to widespread internet issues with CloudFlare and CenturyLink but rather than failing to connect to SE at all a maintenance message is being shown:

[image: Stack Exchange "We are currently offline for maintenance" error screenshot]

<sub>Screenshot provided courtesy of Samuel Liew who wasn't able to access the site</sub>

Comment: I believe this page is send to users by the HA-Proxy from SE when the handling of a request takes more than 5 seconds. In other words, every webserver and SQL Server can be happily up and running, only a bit sluggish ....

Comment: Not sure what is your goal in this question? To change the wording of the message to fit the actual problem?

Comment: @Shadow The goal is to a) find out if/what the problem was b) encourage work to reduce the likelihood again (if possible)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to verify, this was due to the CenturyLink failure. The CDN was serving the maintenance page as the CenturyLink failure caused it to be unable to reach our origin. Seems obvious now. Sorry, new here so still learning.

Comment: Are you working for Stack Exchange?

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask well, their [profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/453464/mike-frank) says there are staff, so yes :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask: [Staff bit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange/322016#322016): *"2019-07-31: Stack Exchange employees (users with the staff bit on their account) are now given a special "Staff" marker in their user profile description. Additionally, the old "moderator" user profile mark has a new style."*

Comment: Also, welcome to Meta, and thanks for the explanation!

Comment: It would be nice to show a staff icon in the (non-expanded) user card, as discussed in https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344019/add-an-immediately-visible-indication-that-a-user-is-a-staff-member-or-an-employ, https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/331658/, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310518/can-we-have-a-square-or-triangle-or-heart-or-something-after-employees-names for example.

Comment: Are you still using Lumen for hosting?

Comment: We are still using Lumen currently