# Should SE Staff have a Special Character in Their User Name?

Tags: feature-request, moderators, display-names

Referring to this question and answer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/281772/4241535 I along with other immediately wondered why a low rep user was editing and posting as if they had the authority of a SE staff member:

[image]

Clicking on [Danny Miller](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2373364/danny-miller) reveals he is a SE Director, but **technically any user could post such a claim in their Bio**.  Danny further writes:

> I'm working on getting a diamond added. As I typically don't "moderate", nor am I a developer, I've never needed the diamond before as the text in my profile usually suffices.

Which indicates he doesn't have the diamond because he doesn't generally "Moderate" and that character is generally reserved for mods.

**Should SE Staff have a special character in their user name and if so which character should they have (a diamond or a different protected character)?**

EDIT:  In the [other linked duplicate question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77883/differentiate-between-employees-and-moderators?lq=1), one of the Mods/Staff mentions that *"We don't want this to be an us vs. you site"* and also *"we like some of our staff to act as normal users under the radar"*. (both quotes paraphrased)  Why shouldn't a staff member have an account specifically marked as staff for posting official responses and a fly-under-the-radar account for interacting with the site?

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm not reluctant to have a "diamond" - it's just never come up as an issue before in the 4 1/2 years I've worked here. It's easy to confirm I'm an employee with the company - http://stackexchange.com/about

Comment: Maybe a unicorn...

Comment: @DannyMiller It's easy enough to confirm that there is an SE employee named "Danny Miller".  There's not an easy way to confirm that you're actually "Danny Miller".  I (or anyone else) could change my username to be any SE employee at any time.

Comment: It's dead easy to confirm if you're *really* suspicious, @Servy: go to [the company team page](http://stackexchange.com/about), click on Danny's picture, click on "recent activity", and note that the post you just read is listed right there.

Comment: @DannyMiller YOU'LL HAVE TO PRY A DIAMOND OUTTA MY COLD, DEAD HAND.

Comment: @Shog9 That's just it; one would need to be pretty suspicious in the first place to go do that.  They'd also need to know the SE system pretty thoroughly.  On the flip side, seeing an "I'm a mod" statement from someone without a diamond stands out like a sore thumb.  Now clearly this hasn't come up a lot as employees that interact with meta a lot tend to already have diamonds, but I certainly would support having all employees get the diamond (or some other user-card indication) automatically, even if they don't interact with the site often.

Comment: Meh; this comes up about once every 6 months @Servy; someone gets momentarily confused and thinks there's a larger issue. If/when it *becomes* a larger issue, we'll figure out a solution.

Comment: It's not against the rules for a normal user to have two accounts. It's just against the rules to use those accounts to game reputation, badges, cigarettes, bitcoins, etc.

Comment: @JarrodDixon - clearly I'm not worthy

Comment: @BilltheLizard Edited per your suggestion.