# Is there a list of SE chat privileges, and the minimum reputation required for those privileges?

Tags: support, chat, privileges, faq-proposed

Is there a list of privileges that users have on any Stack Exchange chat rooms, and which lists the minimum reputation required for each privilege?

If such list doesn't exist, what is the reputation required for the chat privileges?

Comment: related on privileges for various chat domains/servers: [Demystifying chat reputation requirements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/257821/997587)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

[Stack Overflow](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) and [Meta Stack Exchange](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/) each have their own chat; the rest of the network (Stack Overflow in non-English languages, Super User, Server Fault, Stack Exchange 2.0, etc) has a [combined chat site (Stack Exchange chat)](https://chat.stackexchange.com/). Privileges apply based on your total reputation on the associated site(s):

- On SO and MSE chat, privileges apply based on your reputation or moderator status on the associated site.
- On the combined Stack Exchange chat site, privileges apply based on [your total reputation over all sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253487/i-was-able-to-post-in-chat-with-less-than-20-rep/312081#312081). If you have the global association bonus rights, only accounts where you have at least 200 reputation count towards this sum, though all reputation (including bonus rep) on those sites count.

The privilege levels are:

- **public**: read messages in non-private rooms
- **registered**: talk in any room if invited
- **20 reputation**: [participation](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#what) (specifically, talking)
- **100 reputation**:

  1. [bookmark a conversation](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#permalink)
  2. [create a public room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#room-users)
- **1,000 reputation**:

  1. [create a gallery room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#room-users), i.e., a room where messages are public but only specific users can talk
  2. be able to change the access level of a room where you're a room owner from public to gallery and vice versa
- **10,000 reputation**:

  1. be notified of spam/offensive flags (the number of active flags appears in a circle on your gravatar)
  2. view deleted rooms (read access only if allowed).
- **room owner**:

  1. edit the room name and description
  2. [pin a message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#star) (a pin is a super-star)
  3. remove stars from messages
  4. grant explicit read access
  5. grant explicit write access to users with at least 20 reputation
  6. change the access level of the room from public to gallery and vice versa (only if you have 1,000+ rep or are a moderator)
  7. grant and remove room ownership
  8. create and remove feeds
  9. move messages to any other room (provided it's not private or deleted)
  10. schedule events
  11. kick-mute users
  12. put room in timeout (must specify a reason)
  13. view histories of deleted messages (provided they have a link to the message's history, which is only shown in the live room, and the history hasn't been purged)
- **♦︎ moderator** (on chat.SE, moderator on any site, even SO or MSE; your parent site must be set to one where you're a moderator):

  1. all the above<sup>**[1]**</sup>
  2. edit or delete any message at any time
  3. purge a message's history
  4. move messages to private rooms where one has access (see the next section header)
  5. view moderator flags
  6. mark flags as valid or invalid
  7. grant explicit write access to all users even if they don't have 20 reputation
  8. super-ping users (ping users even if they're not pingable in the room or don't have a chat profile)
  9. ban users from chat
  10. annotate users
  11. destroy chat users<sup>**[2]**</sup>
  12. anonymize a user's messages to their user ID<sup>**[2]**</sup>
  13. put a room in timeout without having to specify a reason
  14. freeze/unfreeze room
  15. delete/undelete room, list deleted rooms
  16. be immune to being kicked or suspended from chat
  17. remove the restriction on creating new rooms for a user who has been kicked three times
  18. view a list of recent chat flags raised across all rooms
- **♦︎ moderator on the site** associated with the chat room<sup>**[3]**</sup>:

  1. create private rooms (where only specific users can read content)
  2. see and access private rooms
  3. change the access level of the room from public or gallery to private
  4. change which site is associated with the room
  5. view which user raised a spam/offensive flag on a message (provided that the moderator is in the room where the flag was raised and viewed the flag while it was active)

<sup>**[1]**</sup> When moderators create a scheduled event for the chat room associated with the SE site where they are moderators, the event will be published also in the main site.

<sup>**[2]**</sup> Moderators can only take these actions on users who've posted fewer than 1,000 messages. For users who've posted 1,000 or more messages, only Stack Exchange developers can take these actions. Developers also have access to a modified anonymize messages tool that removes the user's ID from public view.

<sup>**[3]**</sup> For rooms which don't have a parent site set (i.e. are general network rooms), being a moderator anywhere on the network will give you these privileges there as well.

Comment: The [privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges) page covers the big ones too: [participation](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/chat), [create a room](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/chat-rooms), [create a gallery](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/gallery-chat-rooms)

Comment: 10K users should not then see the "blue badge" that reports there are flagged posts. Is that correct?

Comment: @kiamlaluno: That's an undocumented feature. I've made that answer CW so it can serve as a chat privilege FAQ. One thing I don't know is what reputation is taken into account on chat.SE: the total amongst all the relevant sites? or the largest on any relevant site?

Comment: I've added some owner and mod features, I'm not 100% sure if I got the differences between owner and mod right.

Comment: I am getting blue bubbles in the English chatroom; I have 9500ish rep on English, but about 10500 on all SE sites. I think it is related to total rep on SE?

Comment: @Cerberus - Yes, this is correct.  More accurately, these stats are related to your [chat user](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/3420).    Notably, this applies to moderator accounts: If your chat user has a parent account of a site where you're not a mod, then you won't get moderator privileges.