# Do I need 10k Network or 10k site rep to see chat flags?

Tags: support, chat, flags

I recently read about the ability for 10k users to see chat flags network-wide.

Now, my question:

#### Do I need 10k total network rep, or 10k rep on one site to see chat flags?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need 10k network reputation to see flags on [the network chat site](https://chat.stackexchange.com/), as [reported on your chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/73046/undo). This value is your combined reputation across all sites, but [starts excluding your reputation from low-participation sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123468/should-the-account-association-bonuses-be-excluded-when-calculating-totals-for-c/175036#175036) (i.e. ones where you have less than 200 reputation) once you pass the association bonus threshold on any particular site, to prevent abuse.

Naturally you need 10k on the respective site for the two per-site chats (Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange).

Comment: So that same as my network flair, right?

Comment: * Except on Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Overflow which both have separate chat systems.

Comment: @Undo Not quite, the network flair excludes sites where you have < 200 reputation. The value used by chat doesn't have this restriction.

Comment: @TimStone Really? So I just make accounts everywhere, collect the 100 association bonus, and see chat flags?

Comment: @Undo There was another meta post about that asking to exclude association bonus from the chat flair or something of that sort.

Comment: @Undo Also not quite...I have to verify exactly what the behaviour is, but [Marc changed things](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123468/should-the-account-association-bonuses-be-excluded-when-calculating-totals-for-c/175036#175036) to limit abuse.

Comment: @Tim Shoot. Marc always ruins our fun.

Comment: @Undo I've clarified now, for most people the number will now be the same as what they see on their network flair.

Comment: @TimStone OK, I see 8.9k on my flair and 9k in chat. Must be close enough. *You can accept an answer in 3 minutes*...

Comment: @Tim So my [chat profile](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/73046/undo) says I have 10k (I counted on the sites I have >200 and it's about 10,011). Where do I see flags?

Comment: @Undo They'll appear as blue circles down on your avatar when you're in a room, like a notification would. They usually get handled very quickly though.

Answer (score 5):

Depends:

- On chat.SO, you need 10k on Stack Overflow.
- On chat.meta.SO, you need 10k on Meta Stack Overflow
- On chat.SE, you need 10k combined on all sites.

---

So getting 10k on SO or meta.SO will grant you the ability to see chat flags on two of the chat servers.

Comment: Really? So I can't see MSO chat flags if I'm 10k on SO?

Comment: @Undo Correct. There's at least one instance on meta chat where somebody was throwing around flags and I couldn't see them. I had < 10k at the time.

Comment: So my [chat profile](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/73046/undo) says I have 10k (I counted on the sites I have >200 and it's about 10,011). Where do I see flags? – Undo 5 mins ago

Comment: @Undo They show up automatically as bubbles on top of your picture. (like the ping bubbles, but on a different corner) But they are extremely rare on chat.SE. That's because there's hundreds of moderators, so no chat flag lasts more than a few seconds. So unless you're sitting in front of the chat window all day, you'll be lucky to see even 1 in a typical 24-hour period.