# What powers do chat room owners have?

Tags: support, chat, room-owner

The FAQ says:

> Each room has owners, who can change various room settings and transfer ownership to other users.

And:

> There are not a lot of responsibilites connected to room ownership, just a few extra permissions: The owner can add and remove RSS feeds being posted into the room, change room name and description, and similar things.

So what is the full extent of their powers?

Plus, besides revoking ownership, do moderators have any more chat room powers than a room owner?

Answer (score 3):

Most notably, they can move messages from the room into other rooms they have access to. Specifically, in this case, the target room is usually the Bin, effectively removing the message. The only other non-generic power they have is pinning messages, which is like super-starring.

Comment: What 'Bin' are you referring to?

Comment: @ɥʇǝS You can search for “bin” in the room list. A bin is a _**room specifically made for holding unwanted messages**_.

Comment: You can move mesaages to _**any room that you have write access**_.

Answer (score 2):

Room owners can pin messages to the sidebar.  This is similar to starring but is more durable:

> Room owners can also pin messages, which permanently affixes them to the top of the room sidebar for up to 14 days. The room sidebar is intended to be a collaboratively created mini-timeline of interesting room events for people who don't have time to read the entire chat transcript for that particular room.

It's quite hard to see which privileges that community moderators have that room owners don't have without creating a new account as any ♦ moderator is a moderator for the entirety of SE chat.  Therefore there might be some overlap here in terms of what room owners can do, however moderators can **in any room**:

- Place the room in a short penalty timeout
- Freeze the room
- Delete the room
- Directly contact the room owner
- Edit/Delete any message

In addition to all the privileges of a room owner.

See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/87773/176080) also.