# How can I (as the room owner) unstar a message in chat?

Tags: support, chat, chat-stars

Is there a way to unstar a message starred by another user in chat?

The situation is this:

A user recently posted this message in a chat room.

> asl pls

Someone starred it, and now it appears on the sidebar. I really don't think such messages should be displayed on the sidebar, as they are not helpful, informative, or anything else desirable in a chat room.

I am the room owner, but that doesn't give me enough privileges to unstar it. I flagged the message, but the flag was rejected, probably because the message itself wasn't bad. (I am assuming mods can remove stars.) I didn't exactly want to remove the message either.

Is there a way to get a message unstarred? If not, at least one of the following features would be helpful.

- Ability for a room owner to remove stars. (I don't exactly like the idea, but it would work.)
- Ability to enter an explanation when flagging a message. (This might take care of many more misunderstandings.)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Being a room owner gives you the [ability](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/87773/145982) to cancel stars; the option is in the menu in the star list itself:

[image: Screenshot of the cancel stars option]

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I never thought to look there. :(|)