# Chat: how to move a message to another room?

Tags: support, chat

I am a room owner in PHP and occasionally people ask me to delete things.  As I understand it, room owners can't and probably never will be able to do that.  However, according to https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/87773/170584 I should be able to move messages to another room (such as bin). I have just one question: how?  I can't seem to find any way to perform that action. My searches haven't proved helpful as well.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can click the "room" menu in the top right of the room you're owner of...

[image: room menu link]

...and then select the "move messages" option:

[image: room owner menu options]

You'll then be able to select the messages you wish to act on and move them to another room using the "relocate" button:

[image: selected messages with relocate option]

Comment: Fist time I saw that link I thought it was a way to send a message to the admin.

Comment: I didn't find out how to do it until two nights ago.

Comment: Can I move posts that are so old (2 days) to only be in transcript?

Comment: @DoubleAA Hmm, I don't think so, unless you "load older messages" in the live chat view until they're shown to be selected there.

Comment: I attempted to move messages from one chat room to another. I've seen a room owner do it before and it worked fine... But for some reason, when I moved the messages, they did vanish from the source room (as they should) but never appeared in the destination room, even though I see the "3 messages moved from [X]" message in the destination room (and the corresponding one in the source room).

Comment: Is it possible to move a message that was sent a long time ago from the transcript?