# Rename "message admin" in chat

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat

As shown [in this recent Meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155954/chat-how-to-move-a-message-to-another-room), the tool to relocate or delete messages in chat is not easily found. It is hiding behind the "message admin" menu entry, which I personally find rather confusing.

As already suggested in the linked meta post, it should be renamed to something that gives a clear indication of what the tool actually does:

- "Delete/relocate messages" for moderators
- "Relocate messages" for room owners

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a fair point, the wording was indeed ambiguous. Changed.