# Creating gallery chat rooms

Tags: discussion, chat

When I wish to create a gallery chat room, it looks like that's an option for me on Ask Ubuntu.

However, I only have 529 reputation on that site right now. Why can I make this?

Is it network rep that counts in chat, not site-specific rep?

> Update: It's now beginning to look like **this might be a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug).**
>
> ***Update 2: Nope, it's not a bug. According to what [terdon](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/47392/terdon) said [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33829392#33829392), chat rep is network-wide.***

Comment: @rene no, but my network rep is at least 1k.

Comment: Can you actually create the room?  The choice shouldn't even be there if you are under 1k rep.

Comment: Yes, I was able to make it! Look [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49380/this-is-my-test-gallery-room)!

Comment: Hmm, this is either a bug or the requirement changed without updating the help center.

Comment: I can't talk in the room, you created one successfully.

Comment: @JAL I know, it's really weird.

Comment: Can you request access so this comments thread doesn't become a mile long :)

Comment: @Pandya it is a duplicate!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 1124 combined reputation points on chat.SE cluster, as your profile shows: https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/234817/mark-yisri

Whatever number is shown there determines your privileges on chat.SE. It is not inherited directly from any site. Rather, it's the sum of reputation on your sites, including only those with 200+ rep. [Reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/87773).

Comment: Worth to mention this is not relevant for chat.SO and chat.MSE which are on different domain/server.

Comment: @ShadowWizard thanks for the clarification.