# Someone flagged a deleted comment

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, flags, moderator-tools

I just saw this comment flag in the mod queue:

[image]

Note the red background styling and the lack of a delete button.

Turns out that it's a comment on [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/39018/7433) which was deleted yesterday.

This may just be a flag that got accidentally unhandled, but it could also be a more serious bug.

Comment: Possibly linked to this problem?  http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185913/200806

Comment: Could it be it was deleted after being flagged?

Comment: @cole deletion clears comment flags

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an issue in the new flag backfill code - certain flags that should have been marked as handled weren't.

Fixing now.

Comment: Interestingly, I'm able to edit it. (which means that I can edit any deleted comment via AJAX). Doubt that that is a problem though. Editing it temporary dismisses it, but it springs back up on refresh.

Comment: @Manishearth: Why would you edit a deleted comment, though? It can’t be brought back, can it?

Comment: @minitechη I wouldn't. Which is why I said that it wasn't a problem. Also, [comment undeletion is status-planned](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98036/moderators-should-be-able-to-undelete-comments)