# Reputation Spectrum Difference between users with high reputation and moderators?

Tags: discussion, voting, moderators

I read the following lines [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation)

> At the high end of this reputation spectrum there is little difference
>   between users with high reputation and ♦ moderators. That is
>   intentional. We don’t run this site. The community does.

I want to know what is the difference   OR is it lower or higher. Say if they receive more on upvote or less???

Answer (score 6):

I think this is more referring to the powers that are bestowed upon diamond moderators and trusted users.

There's little difference between the two roles except:

- Moderators act and behave in an official capacity on behalf of the community,
- Moderators' votes are binding - they take effect immediately,
- Moderators can view deleted content (such as comments), and have access to more information about a user

...but outside of that, that's about it.  Also, those with a gold badge in a tag have a binding vote on duplicates, which make that power somewhat similar to a moderator's.

You can read a bit more about what diamond moderators' powers are and what their role is [at this FAQ entry](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75192/175248).

Comment: Just to clarify, high-rep non-moderators can see all deleted content *except* for deleted comments. (The software [used to have a loophole](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225182/did-you-know-that-10k-users-can-see-deleted-comments) that would allow high-rep users to view deleted comments, too, but it was closed.) However, moderators do have easier ways *find* deleted content, since they can e.g. see a list of a user's deleted posts.