# Can I view deleted comments that I flagged?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments, flags, declined-flags

Sometimes after I've flagged some comments, I look back through my flag history to see how they're doing: which ones were accepted, declined, and so on. Deleted questions I can of course see, but when I've flagged a comment and it's been deleted, I can never see what it was I flagged. I'd like to be able to compare the comments that I marked as (for example) Not Constructive that were actually deleted with those where my flag was declined, so that I can offer more accurate flags in future. But I don't remember what content I flagged as Not Constructive two months ago in the comments section of [Recursion - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23347681/recursion-java), of course, so I can't compare it with any comments that have had my flags declined.

Is there a way to do this that I'm missing? Is there a reason this would be a bad thing for me to be able to do?

Comment: No. Deleted comments are only ever visible to moderators. [Shog9 explains why regular users seeing them is not going to happen.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/187281)

Comment: @animuson I read that question, and it seems to me that it applies to deleted comments in general; it might be reasonable to make an exception for "comments that I caused to be deleted". I've already seen them anyway, after all: you're not sparing my virgin ears.

Comment: That doesn't seem like a very compelling reason to implement features to let you view them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a ton of infrastructure behind flags on questions and answers, because... Well, those are actually pretty important, and it's crucial that folks are able to make sure they're handled properly.

Comments could *all* be deleted tomorrow, and these sites would still retain most of their utility. They're intended to be a much more light-weight form of communication, and flags are an *even more lightweight* way of moderating them. Adding more support for reviewing these would be a massive undertaking with very little benefit in return; it's unlikely to happen.