# Why did my comment on an answer-converted-to-comment vanish into the void?

Tags: support, comments, new-users, convert-to-comment

I've posted a comment to an answer from a new user, which was later converted to a comment, and now my comment is completely gone (doesn't even show in all-actions), and the answer-now-comment from this user stands uncorrected, making incorrect claims, which I've already refuted in my comment that has apparently vanished into void during the conversion.

[Does Texas have a legal right to leave the Union or secede?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/829/does-texas-have-a-legal-right-to-leave-the-union-or-secede?noredirect=1#comment8390_829)

How do I get to see my comment to repost it as a reply to refute incorrect claims?

(Besides, why wasn't it reposted automatically when the answer was converted to the comment?)

Answer (score 2):

When an answer is converted to a comment using the moderator tools there is a checkbox to determine whether any comments on the answer will be retained.

It sounds like the moderator who performed the conversion did not check that box either intentionally or accidentally.

At a reputation level of 2,000 on [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/) I think you will be able to [see deleted posts](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) but if not, or in the meantime, you could ask in [Law Meta](http://meta.law.stackexchange.com) for someone who can see your comment to copy it out so that you can re-post it.

My understanding is that users can see their own deleted questions and answers but comments are temporary and once deleted they can be considered gone [for most intents and purposes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187279/let-us-view-our-deleted-comments).

Comment: Why is this deemed like a good idea for the user to not see their own full history?  This seems like something over which surely I'm not alone to be pulling my hair?

Comment: My understanding is that users can see their own deleted questions and answers but comments are temporary and once deleted they can be considered gone for most intents and purposes: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187279/let-us-view-our-deleted-comments

Comment: When you post a comment on a post (not your own post), then the post is being deleted, you can't see the comment you made because you can't see the post (unless you have 10k) - but the comment is still there, it's not deleted. /cc @cnst