# deleted comments should show up in user history for moderators

Tags: feature-request, comments, moderator-tools, deleted-comments

There was an incident today where a user posted something... untoward in the comments.  I deleted the comment, but luckily I also copied the User's profile link to a new window before doing so.    Once the comment was deleted, it no longer shows up in the user's profile under the 'comments' section of the 'activity' tab.

[Now that comments are undeletable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98036/moderators-should-be-able-to-undelete-comments), it would be nice (as a moderator) to see all comments a user has left, deleted or not, in their user profile activity page. Why?

- It helps us *easily* track a pattern of behavior (leaving mean comments for other users)
- It also lets us easily copy examples of this behavior to the moderator message section when sending a message to a user that has a history of being mean to other users through comments.
- It's much more discoverable than the ['mod' -> 'info' -> 'comments' way that was raised below](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/187850/16587).

Answer (score 18):

You can already do that, but it is a separate moderator tool at user profile -> mod -> info -> comments. You can see either all comments of that user there or only deleted ones.

Comment: Oy. That's easy to find.

Comment: I absolutely *loved* it when I found that tool!

Answer (score 4):

Maybe there's a scenario I'm not thinking of, but... I don't really love this idea.

For starters, it adds noise to the already very noisy activity feed. Not a *lot* maybe, but every little bit hurts - and how often do you *really* want to see someone's deleted comments?

Beyond that, I would really prefer not to encourage mods to spend any more time micromanaging comments. The intent of the recent changes was *reduce* the time spent doing this on *posts* - you can now delete comments faster, and quickly revert deletions if you hit a useful one accidentally.

The purpose of the mod->info->comments screen you note is twofold:

- Provide evidence when handling users who have a history of leaving abusive comments, even if they've been cleaned up piecemeal in response to flags, etc.
- Provide evidence when handling rare "comment ragequit" users. You can literally count these on the fingers of one hand, but it has happened and been semi-disruptive.

Finally, there's a *small* danger in making deleted comments too visible: I've seen moderators get a bit too worked up over a *single* brusque comment before, something I tend to put down to spending entirely too much time looking at the worst side of people... If a comment is deleted, and inappropriate commentary hasn't become a *habit* for a user then it's probably better to just ignore it most of the time. For the sake of *everyone's* sanity.