# Should this question be moved to Programmers.SE: Efficient ways to use MSDN

Tags: support, specific-question

I noticed my +4 / -1 question was closed as not constructive:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/9338109/328397

Should this be on Programmers.SE?

Comment: (As an aside: [Who are the diamond moderators, and what is their role?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/who-are-the-diamond-moderators-and-what-is-their-role))

Comment: This is the right place if you want to object to your question being closed. But if you're asking whether it belongs on [programmers.se], the right place to ask is [its own meta site](http://meta.programmes.stackexchange.com/). From what I understand of [webapps.se], your question about [using a website](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1/whats-the-difference-between-a-website-and-a-web-app) would be on-topic there.

Comment: @arjan **way** aside, as it was closed by users, not moderators.

Comment: @casper: see original revision

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think if it has been closed and if not any moderator have migrated it, there is no way that it can belong to Programmers.

By the way it's possible to think it fit in "development methodologies" but your question is maybe too much abstract.

Comment: I agree about not going to programmers but not with it possibly fitting under development guidelines.  The question is, in essence "how do I read the manual?" which qualifies as OT, NARQ *and* NC all at the same time.

Comment: I think about "development methodologies" first because code documentation is an essential part of the development (and I'm quite happy that I can easily browse javadoc through an IDE). Then I read his question again and that's true that it's not really answerable.

Comment: You are right, documentation is an essential part of *development* but you'll never find a *development methodology* that has a step saying "read the documentation".

Comment: This answer is incorrect, questions can be migrated to another site even after they've been closed. You just need a moderator. And that moderator needs to agree this question is worth migrating. Now we've come full circle.

Comment: @CodyGray I think you misunderstood my words, I said "has been closed" AND "not migrated". I have never said that questions can't be migrated after be closed. Where you can see that? (funny you're profile image is a pair of glasses...)

Comment: Right, I read what you said. I even read it correctly. It's still wrong. 5 regular users can vote to migrate a question. But even if the question was closed by those 5 regular users and not migrated, a moderator can still migrate the question.

Comment: In my mind it's quite clear. I've edit the question trying to be more clear, it's better?

Comment: Did you miss Arjan's comment to the original question? [There's a big difference between diamond moderators and users with 3k+ reputation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/who-are-the-diamond-moderators-and-what-is-their-role).

Comment: I read the accepted answer. Why? Something wrong in my formulation?

Comment: Yes, it's still wrong. A moderator can still migrate that question.

Comment: I add this fact ***if not any moderator have migrated it***. Maybe if you feel that it's still not precise enough you can edit my post, will be easier. In my mind it's clear I don't get what is wrong Thanks.

Comment: I guess alain.janinm is saying that, if the question has not been migrated to Programmers from a moderator, the question doesn't belong there.