# Can a Valued Associate become Diamond Moderator without election?

Tags: support, election, moderators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Who are the diamond moderators, and what is their role?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/who-are-the-diamond-moderators-and-what-is-their-role)

I think, question title explains everything. I want to know that valued associates need to follow community rules to jump in community or not.

Comment: Yes, employees are generally moderators. Not all of them. The CHAOS team, for example, doesn't have diamonds anymore. Why? What prompted this question?

Comment: @TheEstablishment CHAOS members lost their PSI they never had diamonds to begin with. :)

Comment: @Sha: I was remembering [Joel's comment here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/100359/153008) that they would have temporary diamonds. Looking back, I'm not sure that I ever actually remember those diamonds. I think they took the shape of pitchforks instead, which have [now been lost as well](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110963/did-everyone-on-chaos-get-fired-or-something-what-happened-to-their-pitchforks).

Comment: @TheEstablishment yes indeed, thanks for the link I never noticed that and was wondering why their special symbol was gone. :)

Comment: @TheEstablishment Just curiosity after I seen some criticism of Google because it promoted its own employees on Google+.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd CHAOS members had diamonds on a number of SE 2.0 sites. For the most part, those have since been removed though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many, if not most, Stack Exchange employees have diamonds, yes, and this has nothing to do with being elected. From [Who are the diamond moderators, and what is their role?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/who-are-the-diamond-moderators-and-what-is-their-role):

> In addition, members of the Stack Exchange, Inc. Team have the option to carry diamonds on any site. You can find a list of the Team members on [Stack Exchange's team page](https://stackexchange.com/about/team).

Comment: While you were writing this answer, I was updating the answer you're quoting. Hence my change to your answer just now.

Comment: Thanks, @Pop, I didn't even notice that the company name was wrong.

Answer (score 9):

"Valued Associates" are employees of Stack Exchange.  They have higher privileges (and responsibilities) than diamond moderators (who are community volunteers), so yes they can get a diamond without election.

Comment: note that this isn't *entirely* accurate; there is diamond developer, which is reserved for the development team and does have some dangerous stuff enabled (burninate tag comes to mind), and regular "employee" diamonds, which are the same as regular moderators with a few obscure and mostly irrelevant differences.