# Where's my question?

Tags: support, questions, specific-question

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why was this perfectly legit question removed without any close votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138457/why-was-this-perfectly-legit-question-removed-without-any-close-votes)

I've posted a question in SO and somehow it's gone. I just don't understand why.[image]

the link: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11097234/revisions

Comment: Undeleted.  Usually we wait two days to allow the OP to see what happened, and the community to cast reopen votes (unlikely to happen here).

Comment: I've removed all traces of "shopping," and reopened the question.

Comment: Funny thing is that the words "I don't mind if I have to use an addon to accomplish this" were not written by myself :/ So my question got deleted because someone else try to make my question "better". lol. Thanks for reopening it.

Comment: @gsharp - that [edit was after it was deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11097234/revisions), someone was trying to rescue it I think. It did mirror the language of the original question too.

Comment: @gsharp: I hope you understand what really happened here. That sentence came from me editing your already deleted question in an apparently successful attempt to save it.

Answer (score 3):

It was closed as not constructive by a moderator, then deleted:

[image]

You'll have to ask @CasperOne why he felt this way. He probably felt it was a shopping list request.

Comment: Casper responded in the comments of the duplicate. (And meanwhile the post has been undeleted too.)